# Issue installing Ruby by rvm (error while running configure)

Tags: ruby, rvm

This is what I have, did anyone has an idea to make it configuring correctly ?

```
MacBook-Air-de-Remy-Thellier:~ remythellier$ rvm install 1.9.2
/Users/remythellier/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.2-p0 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 - #extracted to /Users/remythellier/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p0 (already extracted)
ruby-1.9.2-p0 - #configuring 
Error running './configure --prefix=/Users/remythellier/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0 --enable-shared  ', please read /Users/remythellier/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p0/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

Comment: Can we see what is in `configure.log`?

Comment: MacBook-Air-de-Remy-Thellier:~ remythellier$ /Users/remythellier/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p0/configure.log
-bash: /Users/remythellier/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p0/configure.log: Permission denied

Comment: In fact I don't really know how to open it

Comment: why you don't have this read access ?

Comment: use cat : `cat /Users/remythellier/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p0/configure.log`

Comment: MacBook-Air-de-Remy-Thellier:~ remythellier$ cat /Users/remythellier/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p0/configure.log
[2010-12-22 17:56:00] ./configure --prefix=/Users/remythellier/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0 --enable-shared  
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin10.5.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin10.5.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin10.5.0
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/Users/remythellier/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p0':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more de

Comment: It make me that like 10 times

Comment: I am assuming you don't have `gcc` on your `PATH` or installed?

Comment: I don't think so, have you got some links to find and install it ?

Comment: Try installing xcode http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/9/23/install-rails-ruby-mac

Comment: Download and install the [latest version of XCode](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/xcode.html) from Apple. Registration is required, but it's free. The download takes a little while but it contains all the tools needed to compile Ruby.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Install XCode from your OSX cd.  That will give you `gcc` and everything you need to compile the rubies you want to install.

**edit**

Mountain Lion no longer ships `gcc` with XCode, you have to explicitly install it from Preferences -> Downloads -> "Install Command Line Tools" as @boulder_ruby mentioned

Comment: Do NOT install XCode from the DVD. It is known to be buggy. Download and install the [latest version of XCode](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/xcode.html) from Apple. It will take a while, but that will avoid the bugs.

Comment: I've never had issues.  You're also prompted to update your XCode through OSX once you've done that so I wouldn't worry about it.  But downloading is just as easy, so either way.

Comment: Ok I'm gonna try that, thank you everyone for helping me  :)
I hope it will work this time !

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I installed XCode from Apple and now everything work :)

Comment: I have XCode 4, but still having the same issue. Im on 10.7.2, please help. Thanks

Comment: Not only do you have to install xcode, you have to specify that you want the command line tools. See @boulder_ruby's answer.

Comment: ya Mountain Lion requires this now. At the time of the answer XCode came with gcc which is no longer the case, I'll update my answer

Comment: I had to install the Command Line Tools from the terminal, as it was no longer available from the Xcode download options. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-and-later-install-command-line-tools, 'xcode-select --install'

Answer (score 5):

If you have just recently installed Xcode, like me, remember that you have to open it first, which starts the installation wizard.

** Also, make sure you specify the installation of command line tools, which, at least in my case, were not included by default. (key here is the C compiler)
  - inside of Xcode, go to preferences (cmd+,), Downloads, then install command line tools

Answer (score 2):

In addition to boulder_ruby's answer, I also had to update to the latest stable version of RVM in order to get the Ruby to install.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a little late, but if you're having issues like I did, this article is a lifesaver.  You don't just need to install XCode, but also the 'command line tools' which are located in Xcode's preferences:

http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/

Answer (score 1):

Steps I followed for upgrading ruby from 1.8.7 to 1.9.3 (mac osx 10.7)

- Install RVM https://rvm.io/rvm/install/
- Then download install xcode from appstore
- Install command line tools from xcode - Go to `xcode->preferences->downloads->components->commandline tools`
  now run
- '`sudo rvm install 1.9.3`
- `rvm use 1.9.3`