# MonoMac Create Mac Installer results in Merging Mono Failed. FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION

Tags: macos, mono, monodevelop, bundle, monomac

I am using MonoDevelop 2.8.8.4 and MonoFramework (MDK) 2.10.9_8. I'm also using Mac OSX Lion 10.7.3 and have installed XCode 4.3.1 for Lion SDK.  My MonoMac application runs fine when debugging with MonoDevelop. Then I tried to create the Application Bundle by going to Project -> Create Mac Installer...

"Include Mono in Application Bundle" is checked

Linker: is set to "Don't link assemblies"

Everything else is unchecked and grayed out.

When I hit "Create Package" then "Save", MonoDevelop begins to create the bundle but then it fails with:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: ApplicationName='gcc', CommandLine='-mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -m32 /tmp/monomac-build-634690657739224650/AboutToBlowUpDemo.app/Contents/MacOS/driver.m -o /tmp/monomac-build-634690657739224650/AboutToBlowUpDemo.app/Contents/MacOS/AboutToBlowUpDemo -D_THREAD_SAFE -I/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/include/mono-2.0   /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/libmono-2.0.a -framework AppKit -liconv', CurrentDirectory=''  
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_noshell (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0   
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_common (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0   
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0   
  at MonoMac.Bundler.Driver.RunCommand (System.String path, System.String args, System.String[] env, System.String& output) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0   
  at MonoMac.Bundler.Driver.Compile () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0   
  at MonoMac.Bundler.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0   

[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: ApplicationName='gcc', CommandLine='-mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -m32 /tmp/monomac-build-634690657739224650/AboutToBlowUpDemo.app/Contents/MacOS/driver.m -o /tmp/monomac-build-634690657739224650/AboutToBlowUpDemo.app/Contents/MacOS/AboutToBlowUpDemo -D_THREAD_SAFE -I/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/include/mono-2.0   /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/libmono-2.0.a -framework AppKit -liconv', CurrentDirectory=''  
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_noshell (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0   
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_common (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0   
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0   
  at MonoMac.Bundler.Driver.RunCommand (System.String path, System.String args, System.String[] env, System.String& output) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0   
  at MonoMac.Bundler.Driver.Compile () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0   
  at MonoMac.Bundler.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

mmp exited with code 1

Merging Mono failed

I've also tried every other combination in the "Create Mac Installer…" window but I always get the same error. Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install gcc. You do this by installing command line tools in Xcode, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-command-line-tools/9329325#9329325).