# How to uninstall Xcode 5 command line tools (Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks)?

Tags: xcode, macos

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11678882/how-to-uninstall-xcode-4-4-command-line-tools-mac-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion) asks how to remove the command line tools installed with xcode 4.4. I'd like to do it in xcode 5 on OS X 10.9. The problem is that the answer for the previous question talked about a script that would remove files based on these files:

`/var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI.bom`
`/var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI.plist`

I don't have either of these files so this won't work.

So how do I completely remove all the command line tools that were installed when I executed `xcode-select --install`

Comment: Does `xcode-select` have an uninstall option? I believe it does. Check the `man` pages.

Comment: @SevenBits It does not

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635919/how-do-i-uninstall-xcode-5-command-line-tools) might be helpful to you?

Comment: @user2360798 Yup that was it. I saw that before but didn't realize that was what I needed to do.