# Is there an easy way to upgrade XCode Command Line Tools?

Tags: xcode, macos, homebrew

I'm currently on OSX Mountain Lion, but I'm probably going to upgrade my OS pretty soon, either to Mavericks or Yosemite. I'm looking to download command line tools for homebrew; however, looking through the various versions, I'm probably going to have to upgrade command line tools for new versions that are released, and especially if I decide to upgrade my OS.

I've looked at other discussions on StackOverflow that discuss updating, and the threads that I've looked at seem to suggest that uninstalling the old version and then installing the new version is the way to go. However, it seems that the main way to uninstall old versions of command line tools, as mentioned by this thread ([How to uninstall Xcode 4.4 command line tools (Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11678882/how-to-uninstall-xcode-4-4-command-line-tools-mac-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion?rq=1)) is using an unofficial and kind of hack-ish looking script.

Given that new versions are released fairly often and updating is required for an OS upgrade, making upgrading a pretty regular task, it would seem that there would be an easier/smoother way to upgrade. Is there such a way to upgrade? For example, would simply installing another version of command line tools over the previous version be sufficient, cleanly overwriting the previous version? Or is there a way to upgrade through command line?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-and-later-install-command-line-tools)

Comment: @Travis Hm, I did look at that thread before I posted this question; what I got from the top response there was a list of ways to install command line tools, but not really a way to upgrade them. Would just installing the new version over the old overwrite the old version, upgrading it? I just don't want to have an old version hanging around taking up space if I just install the newer version without uninstalling the older version.

Comment: "For example, would simply installing another version of command line tools over the previous version be sufficient, cleanly overwriting the previous version?" Yep!

Comment: @thereislight, by the way, if you want to upgrade to Mavericks, it's easier to do it now, before Yosemite is officially released. Because Apple usually holds only one version of OS in the AppStore, so Mavericks is likely to be removed soon. Personally I recommend upgrading to Mavericks first, because Yosemite will most likely have bugs in the beginning, while Mavericks is rather well-polished already.