# Cross-platform SVN issues, please explain

Tags: macos, svn, terminal, tortoisesvn

I am a Mac-based (10.8) web developer, trying to work with other Windows-based developers.  They are using SVN, although most of them do not check out files to local repositories.  They mostly edit the file on the local server via Explorer, and then use TortoiseSVN shell enhancement to right-click and "commit" what they just edited.

I cannot seem to do this, as my preferred SVN tool Versions (as well as Dreamweaver CS6) require access with the SVN, HTTP, etc. protocols.  I get errors trying to use the file system.

So, I am trying the command line, navigating to the file I need to edit, open it, edit, save.  I can run `svn status` on the directory and I see the file status as "M".  If I try `svn commit -m "updated" myflie.css` or similar, I get an error:

```
svn: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: Local URL 'file://webstage-01/svn/repository/fc-dev/assets/css' contains unsupported hostname
```

I looked in the .svn folder "entries" file an see this:

```
10

dir
20788
file://webstage-01/svn/repository/fc-dev/assets/css
file://webstage-01/svn/repository

2012-06-26T16:08:10.220007Z
20747
JSmith
```

So it looks like that's where it's getting the path from, which is not a valid MacOS or Unix path.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the local server is already a checked out working directory that everyone is sharing. This is the completely wrong and awful way to do Subversion. In the end, you have no idea who is making the change because they're all using the same client. Plus, there's no guarantee that working clients use the same format of the working directory. If someone has a version 1.6 TortoiseSVN on their system, they could damage that working copy.

The correct way is for everyone to checkout a local copy of what's in that Subversion repository to their local machine (Windows or Mac), and then do their changes there and check it in. You won't have the issue of someone messing up that directory. You know who is making the changes. You won't have an issue of what happens if two people try to make the same changes at the same time. It's the way Subversion is suppose to work.

The Mac has the Subversion command line client. (Assuming you're using Mountain Lion -- the latest release) You need to install [XCode](http://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.xcode.html) (free from the Mac App store), and then in XCode, install the [command line tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329325/368630). Look at the [on line Subversion manual](http://svnbook.com) and learn how to do the checkout in Subversion, create your own working directory, and check in from that.

There are many options if you want a Mac OS X GUI Subversion client. I highly recommend you look at Pathfinder](http://cocoatech.com/pathfinder/). It has a built in Subversion GUI client, but it also has many Finder enhancements that make it an excellent Finder replacement -- especially for power users. It's $40, but I think it's worth it just for the built in Terminal client.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. The svn folders on "local server" were created by a platform-specific tool like TortoiseSVN on Windows. Obviously it will have paths, etc. specific to Windows. You will need to checkout separately and make commits.

Also, BTW, set the EOL property to 'native' so that you do not run into cross-platform EOL issues.