# Can not install gfortran via homebrew

Tags: fortran, homebrew, fortran90, gfortran

I got this message when i tried to install gfortran.

```
~$ brew install gfortran
Error: No available formula for gfortran
GNU Fortran is now provided as part of GCC, and can be installed with:
  brew install gcc
```

My question is how to install gfortran with homebrew or port?

or

If now GNU Fortran is a part of GCC How can i compile fortran code using gcc?

I'm not sure may be i've misunderstood something i remember that the last time i still can use gfortran to compile my code but now it doesn't work.

Further information:

when i use command `brew list` i still see that gfortran is there but can not use it.

Further information (latest):

ok, now i can use `gfortran` command but another problem come

```
~$ gfortran-4.9 hello.f
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libcloog-isl.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/f951
  Reason: image not found
gfortran-4.9: internal compiler error: Trace/BPT trap: 5 (program f951)
Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Just do `brew install gcc` per the instructions. The gcc package contains gcc, g++, gfortran etc.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer now i can use `gfortran` command but another problem come.

Comment: It appears that cloog is not installed or is not correctly linked into Homebrew's prefix. Please post the output of `brew doctor` to Gist or a pastebin and link to it.