# El Cap update broke python library

Tags: python, osx-elcapitan

I am using a 2012 MBP for work and just updated to El Cap. We use python via the Pycharm IDE at my work and the update has caused a library we use to stop functioning. The library is called [librefprop](https://github.com/jowr/librefprop.so).

Basically, the update to El Cap has caused this library to no longer function for an unknown reason. At first I thought it was something about the library that was broken. To some extent it was, but I updated gfortran via [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32977363/gfortran-doesnt-work-after-upgrading-to-el-capitan) and that fixed the library. Now the library works when run from it's internal test routines, but the issue is not fixed.

These are pretty nitchy libraries, so it isnt like I expect someone here to know the exact problem, but I was hoping someone might know the general things that El Cap has changed so that I might know where to look next. The

What is more, I know others who updated fine using the exact same libraries, so I am thinking that perhaps some other part of my system is out of date.

Any ideas would be appreciated. The gethub issue conversation can be found [here](https://github.com/jowr/librefprop.so/issues/35).

Comment: first guess is always going to be "system integrity protection" which basically guts root.  see Apple's explanation here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899 --- lots of risk of stuff breaking with this change.  Apparently it can be disabled though.  If the library requires root access, that might be worth disabling it on one machine and see if that fixes. Another possible issue: ElCap messes around with standard locations of binaries etc. & diddles with the path:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270485/after-migration-to-macosx-10-11-el-capitan-how-to-run-simple-utilities-such-a

Comment: Woot! Disabling system integrity protection fixed it. Now to figure out some way to keep my system integrity protected and still get any work done...