# Is it possible to get a downgraded version of gfortran?

Tags: version-control, fortran, gfortran

Is it still possible to somehow get a downgraded version of gfortran? Currently I have version 10.2.0 but this leads to some incompatibility in the compilation of some fortran code in a package I wish to install. As I am on a new machine, it is probably ok for me to uninstall gfortran without too much problems elsewhere but I couldn't see how I might then get a downgraded version of gfortran. I am looking for gfortran version 9.1.0 and I am on a MacOs Big Sur operating system.

Answer (score 0):

All versions of gfortran are available. You can get the source code and compile yourself.

You can also get the binaries for many operating systems. Specifically for MacOS homebrew allows selecting a specific version of the package:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9832084/721644
[homebrew - how to install older versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187812/homebrew-how-to-install-older-versions)
Try `brew search` to find what is available first. Homebrew does not allow simple downgrading but you can have multiple versions using https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/222645

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it seems the `brew install gfortran@9.1.0` and `brew search gfortran` do not give me any useful results. The latter for example just returns ===> Casks gfortran (tick)

Comment: @CAF On Linux if I am not the admin I normally  go via the compiling the source coude route and it should work on MacOS too. It is not that hard. If you do need the binary, you need to find out which versions are available in the package manager history, try `brew search gcc` and `brew search gfortran` and consider https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/222645

Comment: @CAF GCC includes gfortran.

Comment: I see ok I installed gcc@7. But when I do `which gfortran` it says I don't have it. But if gfortran is part of gcc why is that so?

Comment: @CAF I do not know, I do not use Mac. Too many complications like yours. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26919450/can-not-install-gfortran-via-homebrew

Comment: @CAF One can only compile the complete GCC. Gfortran is an integral part of GCC. The GCC sources are at the official site https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html and the releases contain compilation instructions. The script to download any prerequisities is incuded. One needs to set the prefix  (default is /usr/local but you probably want $HOME) and enable fortran during configure.