# How to setup SVN on Mac OS X 10.8.2?

Tags: macos, svn, installation

I have found information that SVN comes with Mac OS X. But there was no SVN on my system. I have installed `Subversion-1.6.17-1_10.7.x.pkg` and all was good. But after update to Mac OS X 10.8.2 all SVN files were automatically removed from the system. I have tried to install `Subversion-1.6.17-1_10.7.x.pkg` again - but Next button is disabled. I have tried to found an updated version - but there is no Mac OS support now.

How to simply setup SVN on Mac OS X 10.8.2?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Yes, xCode is installed. The latest version.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think it comes with XCode or with the XCode tools. Did you install XCode (and the tools)?

I have both XCode and the tools installed, and I do have svn. But I'm on Lion, not Mountain Lion. I do not have a Mountain Lion machine to check.

Comment: I have installed xCode from the AppStore. It didn't ask me to seleced or deselect any components (tools).

Comment: Launch Xcode and then install the command line tools - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9329325/253056

Comment: You can also Homebrew it. TL;DR: `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"; brew update;` Then `brew install svn` for latest (1.8 at the time of this writing). Or, if you need svn 1.7 (say, for IDE integration) `brew tap homebrew/versions; brew install subversion17`. [Read more](http://michaelsanford.com/using-subverison-1-7-with-phpstorm-webstorm-or-intellij-idea-on-mac-os-x/).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After you have installed Xcode 4.5 you need to follow [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329325/253056) in order to install the command line tools. Once you've done that successfully then you should see that  svn is installed:

```
$ which svn
/usr/bin/svn
$ svn --version
svn, version 1.6.18 (r1303927)
   compiled Aug  4 2012, 19:46:53

Copyright (C) 2000-2009 CollabNet.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.apache.org/
This product includes software developed by CollabNet (http://www.Collab.Net/).

The following repository access (RA) modules are available:

* ra_neon : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using Neon.
  - handles 'http' scheme
  - handles 'https' scheme
* ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol.
  - handles 'svn' scheme
* ra_local : Module for accessing a repository on local disk.
  - handles 'file' scheme

$
```

Comment: The sad truth is its far more simple to get a VM, launch windows 7, and install TortoiseSVN.

xcode? lol, no.

Comment: Ha, right, that's definitely simpler!