# Brew - node did not build

Tags: macos, node.js, homebrew

Homebrew 0.9.3
OSX 10.8.2

I'm wondering if you have seen anything like this?

```
==> make install
brew: superenv removed: -O3 -gdwarf-2 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter
20 errors generated.
make[1]: *** [/private/tmp/node-tiuh/node-v0.8.12/out/Release/obj.target/uv/deps/uv/src/unix/darwin.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [node] Error 2

Error: node did not build
Logs: /Users/justin/Library/Logs/Homebrew/node/
Help: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
      https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/13282
```

Comment: Have you followed the instructions on the [troubleshooting page](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting)?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error.

Open up XCode
go to XCode->Preferences
go to the Downloads tab and install command line tools (or update them)
If you dont have Xcode, you can also download them separately

[Xcode 4.4 and later install Command Line Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-command-line-tools)