# Can't install numpy on Mountain Lion

Tags: python, numpy, nltk

I'm completely new to Python, I'm trying to install NLTK based on http://nltk.org/install.html

I've got everything installed except for `numpy` (it says `numpy` is optional but when I try to import `nltk`, it says there's an error because it couldn't find the `numpy` module)

after I run `sudo pip install -U numpy`

I'm running on a Mac with Mountain Lion, python v2.7.3

I get the following error (I only included the end of log):

> File "/private/tmp/pip-build/numpy/numpy/core/setup.py", line 696, in get_mathlib_info
>
> raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")
>
> RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
>
> ---
>
> Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build/numpy

Has anyone seen this happen?

Comment: Does it act happy enough about compiling the programs?  i.e. Do you have a compiler installed and configured properly?

Comment: If you use the OS X system Python 2.7 (`/usr/bin/python2.7`), Apple already includes versions of `setuptools` and `numpy` with it so you wouldn't need to install them with that Python.

Answer (score 2):

If you open a command prompt and type `gcc` does it run without error? If not, you may need to install XCode (available on the appstore) and then the command line tools ([it looks similar to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-command-line-tools)) so that you can complete the install for numpy.

Answer (score 2):

Recently I had been seeing this along with:

> clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd'
>   [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]

See here to fix:

[clang error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' (python package installation failure)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/clang-error-unknown-argument-mno-fused-madd-python-package-installation-fa)

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like this question has already been answered here: [Problems with pip install numpy - RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388519/problems-with-pip-install-numpy-runtimeerror-broken-toolchain-cannot-link-a)

Setting `ARCHFLAGS` enabled me to install numpy (running Mavericks with Command Line tools 5.1.1):

`ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install --upgrade numpy`