# Problems with pip install numpy - RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program

Tags: python, numpy, virtualenv, pip

I'm trying to install numpy (and scipy and matplotlib) into a virturalenv.

I keep getting these errors though:

```
RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
```

I have the command line tools for xcode installed

```
$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
$ which cc
/usr/bin/cc
```

I'm on Mac OSX 10.9
Using a brew installed python

**Edit**
Yes, trying to install with pip.
The whole traceback is huge (>400 lines)

Here is a section of it:

```
C compiler: cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe



compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -Inumpy/core/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c'

cc: _configtest.c

clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]

clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future

clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]

clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future

failure.

removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/Users/bdhammel/Documents/research_programming/julia_env/build/numpy/setup.py", line 192, in <module>

    setup_package()

  File "/Users/bdhammel/Documents/research_programming/julia_env/build/numpy/setup.py", line 185, in setup_package

    configuration=configuration )

  File "/Users/bdhammel/Documents/research_programming/julia_env/build/numpy/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup

    return old_setup(**new_attr)

  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup

    dist.run_commands()

  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands

    self.run_command(cmd)

  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "/Users/bdhammel/Documents/research_programming/julia_env/build/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/egg_info.py", line 10, in run

    self.run_command("build_src")

  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command

    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "/Users/bdhammel/Documents/research_programming/julia_env/build/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 153, in run

    self.build_sources()

  File "/Users/bdhammel/Documents/research_programming/julia_env/build/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 164, in build_sources

    self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)

  File "/Users/bdhammel/Documents/research_programming/julia_env/build/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 299, in build_library_sources

    sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))

  File "/Users/bdhammel/Documents/research_programming/julia_env/build/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 386, in generate_sources

    source = func(extension, build_dir)

  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 674, in get_mathlib_info

    raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")

RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
```

Comment: Lol @ "cannot link a simple C program". Such sass!

Comment: Get ready for a flood of newbies in 202X who naturally install `python2.x` in their favorite virtual environment, then do a `pip install mypackage'.  Causing pip to bring you here.  I think the python2 forced retirement is a bit too aggressive.  A working virtual machine with python2 and pip  that just works and runs legacy python written 5 and 10 years ago, will trade for many coins.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

While it's ugly, it appears to work

```
sudo ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install --upgrade numpy
```

Note that if you are getting this error for a package other than numpy, (such as lxml) specify that package name instead of `numpy` at the end of the commnd.

I saw a similar issue someone was having with installing a gem

[Ruby Gem install Json fails on Mavericks and Xcode 5.1 - unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352838/ruby-gem-install-json-fails-on-mavericks-and-xcode-5-1-unknown-argument-mul)

This is only a temporary fix, at some point the compiler options will have to be fixed

Comment: @Ben: FWIW, I have the same issue (not using brew). It appeared after updating Xcode to 5.1. However ugly, this does appear to be the answer (for now).

Comment: There is an explanation in the [XCode 5.1 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/developertools/rn-xcode/xc5_release_notes/xc5_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH2-SW12).

Comment: Is `unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future` still needed with the latest Xcode under Yosemite? Things seem to work (at least for the packages I've tired) without it.

Comment: Anyone have  a windows solution?

Answer (score 178):

For Docker (Alpine) and Python 3.x this worked for me:

```
RUN apk update
RUN apk add make automake gcc g++ subversion python3-dev
```

Comment: For anyone using docker python3 alpine image, this is the solution.

Comment: I needed an `apk update` first, otherwise I got a `ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints` message.

Comment: This is also the solution for the docker python2 alpine image.

Comment: I was able to do this on alpine with only `gcc g++ make python3-dev` for numpy/nmslib. The cause of this particular issue seems to be the missing c++ compiler `g++` (it looks by the error that `gcc` and `make` are already installed). The other important parts of `numpy` build is the python3 headers which come with `python3-dev`.

Comment: Not sure, if `subversion` is necessary. The official Python docker base on `buildpack-deps` where subversion is not listed.

Comment: The list of packages that helped me is `g++ jpeg-dev zlib-dev libjpeg make`. Not sure what each of them is for.

Answer (score 19):

The problem is that you are unable to compile.

First, make sure that you have accepted the new Terms and Conditions with Xcode. To do this, just open up xCode and accept.

Then, try installing gcc with

```
brew install gcc
```

Finally, try to install Numpy with

```
pip install numpy
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this worked for me. Problem was I didn't open up xcode and accept terms and conditions.

Comment: For those running **Big Sur Beta**: (1) download and install [Command Line Tools for Xcode 12.2 beta 3](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/) (2) on terminal type `sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` (3) `brew install gcc` (4) `pip install numpy`

Answer (score 10):

If you don't want to use sudo (so permissions and things like that are preserved when using venv), you can add the ARCHFLAGS declaration to your .bash_profile, and run as normal. This worked for me with Mavericks and Xcode 5.1 using with venv:

In ~/.bash_profile:

> export ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future

Then, just run the command:

> pip install --upgrade numpy

Comment: the `sudo` above is for system-wide installation, can run without in a virtualenv

Answer (score 8):

If you are running a linux distribution, you may need a C compiler, especially if you see telltale log lines like `sh: gcc: command not found`.  You can follow the instructions [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-compile-and-run-c-cplusplus-code-in-linux/), which I've summarized below:

- Fedora, Red Hat, CentOS, or Scientific Linux

  `# yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'`
- Debian or Ubuntu Linux

  `$ sudo apt-get update
   $ sudo apt-get install build-essential manpages-dev`

Then you can try rerunning:

```
sudo pip install numpy
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case this happened during a docker build. The problem was that the base image wasn't fixed to a specific python version and numpy couldn't compile with the new one.

```
FROM python:3-slim  # BAD
```

After I changed it to the following it worked:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim  # GOOD
```

Remember to fix your versions! :-)

Comment: Same thing cropped up for me today. Looks like they removed the c compiler + associated make utilities in 3.9.0.

Answer (score 5):

I simply had to open XCode and accept the agreement and let it install the tools.  I then went back to PyCharm and installed numpy again with no issues.

Answer (score 5):

On Fedora 22 this was resolved by updating pip itself:
`sudo pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: The same solution worked for a problem with MacOS on Big Sur

Answer (score 4):

For fedora users that are having a similar problem try installing these packeges:

(if not using python3 use python-devel and pip instead of pip3)

```
sudo dnf install python3-devel
sudo dnf install make automake gcc gcc-c++ gcc-gfortran
sudo dnf install redhat-rpm-config
sudo dnf install subversion
```

then try

```
sudo pip3 install numpy
```

Answer (score 3):

In some cases after OS X upgrades XCode, XCode will require the user (with administrative privileges) to accept a new license. Until the license is accepted, clang and gcc will issue an error when attempting to compile and link code. Or at least python packages.

If you launch XCode and accept the license, the errors no longer appear.

At least, this was the case for me.

Answer (score 2):

### **The Error:**

> RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program

Means it either can't find your C compiler or encountered problems linking a simple C program.

### Demo docker walkthrough, to get Python2/pip to puke that error:

Keeping this demo confined inside a read-only docker image helps us be fearless in issuing OS-wrecking root level commands and start fresh every time:

```
#download a read only docker image that doesn't have gcc installed:
docker pull frolvlad/alpine-python2

#check the version of pip and python:
docker run --rm frolvlad/alpine-python2 pip --version
#pip 20.3.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python
```

Try to pip install numpy, you can't because pip needs gcc:

```
docker run --rm frolvlad/alpine-python2 pip install --user numpy
#...
#RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
```

gcc clearly not installed:

```
docker run --rm frolvlad/alpine-python2 which gcc
#empty output, gcc is not installed
```

So install it, now the binary /usr/bin/gcc exists:

```
docker run --rm frolvlad/alpine-python2 sh -c "apk update && apk add make automake gcc g++ subversion python2-dev && which gcc"
#/usr/bin/gcc
```

Apologies for stacking terminal commands but this is a read only image so everything has to be redone every time:

Now pip can use gcc and install numpy for python2:

```
docker run --rm frolvlad/alpine-python2 sh -c "apk update && apk add make automake gcc g++ subversion python2-dev && pip install numpy && python -c 'import numpy as np; print(np.__name__, np.__version__)'"
# ...
#Successfully installed numpy-1.16.6
#('numpy', '1.16.6')
```

We're in a good place so freeze the docker image and rename it.

```
docker images
#choose the most recent container id: 751420a548c1:latest and rename it:
docker commit 751420a548c1:latest frolvlad/alpine-python2_numpy
```

Now you have a new read only docker image with python2, pip and updated 1.16.6 numpy, ready to run your legacy python2 software like it's 2005:

```
docker run --rm frolvlad/alpine-python2_numpy python -c 'import numpy as np; print(np.__name__, np.__version__)'
#('numpy', '1.16.6')
```

### Or to make the above commands simpler and sequential:

Use the `-it` flag on `docker run` which means open an interactive terminal from the docker image:

```
$ docker run -it frolvlad/alpine-python2_numpy sh
/ > python2 -c 'import numpy as np; print(np.__version__)'
1.16.6
/ > which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
/ > python2 -c 'import numpy as np; print(np.zeros(3))'
[0. 0. 0.]
/ > echo "headward free now to rise"; exit;
```

As python2 packages fall further into ancient history, pip will have to be configured to point at your a private python2 package repository url.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using Conda instead of pip in my Dockerfile:
`FROM continuumio/miniconda3:latest`

Answer (score -1):

Old thread, by my problem was that I didn't have Xcode installed. The following solved it.

```
xcode-select --install
```