# RuntimeError raised when install NumPy by using pip on Windows 7

Tags: python, numpy, pip

The version is Python 3.4 with pip, along with Visual Studio 2010 in the Windows 7 OS. When I run `pip install numpy` in the cmd, it gives:

> File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 682, in get_mathlib_info raise 
>   RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program") 
>   RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program

Comment: If you haven't already, check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22411624/2297365).

Comment: @Huu Nguyen Thank you for the answer. I read the page. However, it is dedicaded to an issue in MacOS. Mine is in Win7, so the answer is not very much help for me.

Comment: The top answer of the linked question says: Run Sudo . That doesn't help on Windows. Therefore this question deserves reopening.

Comment: Featured in *[Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange Site Lesson 50a](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=st_SSPTjBTs&t=110)*.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a binary installer. You can find it here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy