# Using Python with homebrew on OS X

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, pip, homebrew

I have been using Mac python for a while, and I decided to teach myself `matplotlib`, because I want to have the experience with some common modules. I hear from everyone that once you get into non-standard modules, it's best to use python threw homebrew, so you have access to `pip` and not `easy_install`. After running: `$brew install python --with-brewed-openssl`, `$brew install python3 --with-brewed-openssl`, and `$pip install matplotlib`, I go to the python shell with `$python3`. Once there, I run `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, and get the following:

```
Python 3.4.1 (v3.4.1:c0e311e010fc, May 18 2014, 00:54:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib'
>>>
```

I have a feeling I'm still using the mac python, and not the brewed python, and I have tried editing the path, but it isn't working, even though I am running `$source ~/.bash_profile` after every edit. Just in case I am editing the path wrong, I will post the file contents below:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/iOSOpenDev/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin
PATH=/usr/local/opt/ruby193/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/iOSOpenDev/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin
export MSF_DATABASE_CONFIG=/usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/database.yml

PATH="/Users/ericmarkmartin/.apportable/SDK/bin:$PATH"

PATH="/Users/ericmarkmartin/.apportable/SDK/bin:$PATH"

# Setting PATH for Python 3.4
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"
PATH=“/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}”
export PATH
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/Users/ericmarkmartin/.apportable/SDK/bin:/Users/ericmarkmartin/.apportable/SDK/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby193/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/iOSOpenDev/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/ericmarkmartin/.rvm/bin
PATH=/usr/local/opt/ruby193/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/Users/ericmarkmartin/.apportable/SDK/bin:/Users/ericmarkmartin/.apportable/SDK/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby193/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/iOSOpenDev/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/ericmarkmartin/.rvm/bin
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/opt/ruby193/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/Users/ericmarkmartin/.apportable/SDK/bin:/Users/ericmarkmartin/.apportable/SDK/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby193/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/iOSOpenDev/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/ericmarkmartin/.rvm/bin
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/iOSOpenDev/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/opt/ruby193/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/Users/ericmarkmartin/.apportable/SDK/bin:/Users/ericmarkmartin/.apportable/SDK/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby193/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/iOSOpenDev/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/ericmarkmartin/.rvm/bin:/Users/ericmarkmartin/.rvm/bin
PATH=/usr/local/opt/ruby193/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/iOSOpenDev/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/opt/ruby193/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/Users/ericmarkmartin/.apportable/SDK/bin:/Users/ericmarkmartin/.apportable/SDK/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby193/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/iOSOpenDev/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/ericmarkmartin/.rvm/bin:/Users/ericmarkmartin/.rvm/bin

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function

# Setting PATH for MacPython 2.6
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:${PATH}
```

`$pip3 install matplotlib` returns the following

```
RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/sr/j0s763cj06v38c6btg6v7k7r0000gn/T/pip_build_ericmarkmartin/matplotlib
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/ericmarkmartin/.pip/pip.log
```

If more information is needed, please feel free to ask, and thank you so much in advance for the help!

Comment: Try using a verbose flag `pip --verbose install matplotlib` and see which Python version mentioned.

Comment: Hopefully [THIS](http://www.tapir.caltech.edu/~dtsang/python.html) will help :)

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, I will check it out in the morning and gladly mark this as a solution of it works out.

Comment: I followed [these](http://hackercodex.com/guide/python-development-environment-on-mac-osx/) instructions to get homebrew and python installed on Mavericks, and everything works fine now, including `pip` and `virtualenv`. Hope this can help you out as well.

Comment: What do `which python3` and `head -1 $(which pip3)` return?

Comment: @Kristof That's funny actually, I used those instructions too. Thanks for the suggestion though. @TanmayaMeher I thanks for the suggestion, but I already had all of those packages installed in brew, so it didn't fix. @TimSmith `$which python3` returns /usr/local/bin/python3 which is an alias that points to an executable in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/. `$head -1 $(which pip3)` returns #!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4.

Answer (score 1):

`pip` usually installs modules for `python2` if you have both python versions in your system, so for `python3` you will probably need to use `pip3`.

For reference:
   https://docs.python.org/3.4/installing/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the response! However, I already tested the import on python2, and running pip3 doesn't change anything.

Comment: I think this might help [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388519/problems-with-pip-install-numpy-runtimeerror-broken-toolchain-cannot-link-a, it seems to be a problem with native extensions on OSX, so you should use ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future $pip3 install --upgrade matplotlib

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That seemed to work for `pip install --upgrade numpy` and `pip install --upgrade matplotlib` but no success with either `pip3 install --upgrade numpy` or `pip3 install --upgrade matplotlib` in addition, `import matplotlib` still fails in both python and python3.

Answer (score 0):

You can check where a command is coming from by using `which python` .  In this case you are adding `/opt/local/bin/` to your path, but then you are adding `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin` and `/usr/local/bin/` before them (you are prepending in each case).  $PATH stops on the first successful match, so you won't pick up the python from `/opt/local/bin` . Try moving that line to the end of your bashrc or adding another line prepending it to the front of $PATH.

Comment: is /opt/local/bin where brew keeps it's python's. I thought it kept it in the cellar. Also, /opt/local/bin doesn't exist on my computer

Comment: I was confusing homebrew and macports; macports is the one that uses /opt/local/bin/ .  What does `which python3` return for you?

Comment: The result of `which python3` can be found above in one of my comments.  Homebrew keeps its stuff in /usr/local/Cellar.