# Path is in correct order: Still points to Unbrewed Python

Tags: python, homebrew

I want to use my brewed version of python but although many forums say to adjust path order so that your OS X python which corresponds to path /usr/bin is not used. I find that although my paths are set in the correct order that I still am calling the old OS X python.

```
justins-mbp:~ justinthong$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

As you can see when I use `which python` command it still gives me the original path.

```
justins-mbp:site-packages justinthong$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

I am trying to be careful on not to force a symlink.

Comment: `which` doesn't look at `/etc/paths`; it looks at the current value of `PATH` in your environment.

Comment: @chepner Hi I just edited. `$PATHS` gives me the same order

Comment: The solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45170852/installing-homebrew-python-and-linking

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Homebrew Python and linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45170852/installing-homebrew-python-and-linking)

Answer (score 0):

Running:

```
brew info python
```

gives the answer to your question:

> This formula installs a python2 executable to `/usr/local/bin`.
>   If you wish to have this formula's python executable in your `PATH` then add
>   the following to `~/.bash_profile`:
>
> `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"`