# No module named yaml (brew broke my python, again)

Tags: python, python-2.7, homebrew, requirements.txt

`homebrew` has again broken python for about third time. Im now having issues getting dependencies to work again. At this point I am unable to install `yaml`.

`Collecting yaml
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement yaml (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for yaml`

Some other suggestions have said to try `pyaml`, which again simply tries to import `yaml` and fails

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 13, in <module>
    import pyaml
  File "/~/virtualenv/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyaml/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    import os, sys, io, yaml
ImportError: No module named yaml`

Anyone have an idea how to get this sorted out?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two packages with somewhat unfortunate naming in the [Python Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi).

- `pip install pyyaml` lets you `import yaml`.  [This package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyYAML) enables Python to parse YAML files.
- `pip install pyaml` lets you `import pyaml`.  [This package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyaml) allows pretty-printing of YAML files from Python, among other things.  It requires `pyyaml` to be installed.

So the way forward for you is:

1. Install `pyyaml`, preferably using pip
2. Install `pyaml`
3. Profit

Step 0 would be to run everything from a [virtual environment](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/#virtualenvwrapper) to prevent homebrew from messing with your Python ever again.  This option also lets you run multiple versions of Python, not just the one required by homebrew.

Comment: I was having the same trouble in the virtual environment. I will try installing both `pyaml` and `pyyaml`. Thanks man!

Comment: I'm curious how this will work if `yaml ` is still missing. Since `pyaml` tries to import it: `/pyaml/__init__.py", line 6, in <module> import os, sys, io, yaml` @misha

Comment: Why would it be missing? You installed it in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me turned out to be [homebrew changing `python` to `python2`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45170852/installing-homebrew-python-and-linking), which I believe precludes using the brew version instead of the system version

eg `python script.py` >> `python2 script.py`

Additionally, linking the system version of `python` to the brew `python2` version helped as well:

`cd /usr/local/bin && ln -s ../Cellar/python/2.7.13_1/bin/python2 python`

I'm also hesitant the accepted answer will work, as `pyaml` is still attempting to `import yaml`, via `__init__.py`; which does not exist even after installing both packages

```
$ pip install pyaml 
Collecting pyaml
  Using cached pyaml-17.7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML in ~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyaml)
Installing collected packages: pyaml
Successfully installed pyaml-17.7.2
$ pip install yaml 
Collecting yaml
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement yaml (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for yaml
```

eg

```
  File "/~/virtualenv/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyaml/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    import os, sys, io, yaml
```

Comment: This was helpful as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34303294/how-to-fix-broken-python-2-7-11-after-osx-updates