# Python: Broken toolchain error while installing numpy

Tags: python, python-2.7, visual-studio-2008, numpy, pip

I am using Python 2.7.3 and trying to install the package numpy on my windows machine but I am getting a Runtime error that says  Broken toolchain: cannot link to a simple C program. I read the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388519/problems-with-pip-install-numpy-runtimeerror-broken-toolchain-cannot-link-a) but it was specific to Mac OS. I tried installing numpy with pip as well as the setup.py install option but both the methods give the same error.

I recently installed Visual Studio 2008 and Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 (this is necessary as VS 2008 does not provide a 64 bit compiler) to remove the "vcvarsall.bat not found" error. Are these two error related or am I missing something in the process? Please help!

Also, after installing VS 2008, I have VS90COMNTOOLS in the system variable. What can be the problem for Broken toolchain error?

Comment: Unless you need to build it yourself for some reasons I would suggest to use a binary installer. e.g. from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/ or here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

Comment: Make sure to use an installer which matches your Python install, e.g. for Python 2.7.x 32 use a Py27-32bit installer of numpy.

Comment: @Werner thanks! It worked. It seems binary installer is better than building it manually.