# Installing Numpy on 64bit Windows 8.1 with Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, windows-8.1

I am trying to install Numpy on Python 2.7 and I am using Windows 8.1. When I run Numpy from this [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.8.0/) it says, "Python 2.7 required, which was not found in the registry ". How can resolve this issue, I already installed Python 2.7?

Comment: How did you install Python?  The point is that it should be n the registry.  Maybe it was installed specifically for a different user?

Comment: @cdarke: i installed Python using this (method)[http://www.anthonydebarros.com/2014/02/16/setting-up-python-in-windows-8-1/]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use pip to install Numpy and any other librarys

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows?rq=1) for how to install pip

after installing, go to your command line and enter

```
pip install numpy
```

Comment: Yes I download get-pip.py, Then, run it from the command prompt.

`python get-pip.py`
after installing that,  i wrote as suggested `pip install numpy`.
but after that it gives me error:  Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Comment: That's because you don't have Microsoft visual C++ installed. Some parts of Python modules written in C/C++ ( to boost speed), so you need something to compile C/C++ code.
Just download from: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266

Comment: I again reinstalled Python 2.7.9, and pip. but this time when i am running `pip install numpy` it gives me this (error) [https://www.dropbox.com/s/pzf3ahwpvl8lerd/Capture.PNG?dl=0]

Answer (score 2):

For Windows, you should check out Chris Gohlke's page:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs

He has some Numpy builds there for Python 2.7.

Comment: Yes I downloaded **numpy-1.9.2+mkl-cp27-none-win_amd64** , and opeded it using Winzip. What should i do after that to install?

Comment: I believe the file you downloaded is a "wheel" distribution. See [this page](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#installing-from-wheels) for installing a wheel using pip. Make sure to read through the front-matter from Gohlke's page. It has this info, plus stuff about Visual Studio redistributable packages.

Answer (score 1):

You can first install wheel using pip.

```
pip install wheel
```

Then download the .whl file for Numpy from [Chris Gohlke's page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Then go to the directory where you downloaded the package.whl file in cmd and do the following

```
pip install package_you_downloaded.whl
```

I experienced a similar broken toolchain error while installing Numpy. You can check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176688/python-broken-toolchain-error-while-installing-numpy).

Answer (score 1):

I changed to anaconda a while ago and in my mind its the best and most dynamic package manager for all platforms.
http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install.html

Answer (score 1):

correct command after installing pip is:

`python -m pip install numpy`