# Python Pip Install "Egg" Error (Pandas and other modules)

Tags: python, macos, installation, pip, easy-install

Having issues installing some python modules (for example pandas) and also had some issues installing ipython notebook.

This error seems to have come up before for other folks ([Python pip install fails: invalid command egg_info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425106/python-pip-install-fails-invalid-command-egg-info)), but they were using Python 2.7, whereas I'm using 2.6 (default with my Mac OS 10.6). Also I tried easy_install -U setuptools and pip install --upgrade setuptools but neither worked.

This is the error I get for installing pandas:

```
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/Wm/WmmbYincEnuCrAMtGBudAk+++TM/-Tmp-/pip_build_AWal/pandas
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/AWal/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

For installing iPython, this is the error that I get:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.6.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.6.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.6.egg/pip/req.py", line 1435, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.6.egg/pip/req.py", line 671, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.6.egg/pip/req.py", line 901, in move_wheel_files
    pycompile=self.pycompile,
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.6.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 341, in move_wheel_files
    generated.extend(maker.make_multiple(['%s = %s' % kv for kv in console.items()]))
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.6.egg/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 316, in make_multiple
    filenames.extend(self.make(specification, options))
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.6.egg/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 305, in make
    self._make_script(entry, filenames, options=options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.6.egg/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 209, in _make_script
    self._write_script(scriptnames, shebang, script, filenames, ext)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.6.egg/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 189, in _write_script
    self._fileop.write_binary_file(outname, script_bytes)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.6.egg/pip/_vendor/distlib/util.py", line 384, in write_binary_file
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/sphinx-apidoc'

Storing debug log for failure in /Users/AWal/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

Any thoughts on what to do?

UPDATE:

When I do sudo pip install pandas (another module that I can't install), I get a long long traceback with the end error message:

```
RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
```

And traceback (a sample of it of the 100 or so lines) looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/pandas/setup.py", line 619, in <module>

    **setuptools_kwargs)

  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/core.py", line 113, in setup

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 266, in __init__

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 312, in fetch_build_eggs

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 753, in resolve

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1005, in best_match

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1017, in obtain

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 379, in fetch_build_egg

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 619, in easy_install
```

Comment: try wiht admin right

Comment: @Hackaholic Tried sudo pip install pandas (another module that is not working), and I got the same error: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip_build_root/pandas
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/AWal/Library/Logs/pip.log

Comment: This might be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388519/problems-with-pip-install-numpy-runtimeerror-broken-toolchain-cannot-link-a

Comment: Do you have XCode (and the tools it brings with itself) installed on your OS X?

Comment: @sthzg I don't have xCode that I could find. Is there a way to easily install it?

Comment: @user3736169 Yes, you can just download it from the Mac App Store. Not 100% sure, but I think installing and opening it brings all the C-based compile tools to life.

Answer (score 0):

A permission Denied message would suggest you to run your command as root as suggested by  Hackaholic.
try `sudo pip install YOUR_PACKAGE`

You might also want to have a look at `virtualenv` to use a more isolated environment.
Under debian based distributions, you might install python-virtualenv package with `apt-get install python-virtualenv`.

Then create a virtual environment names whatever by typing `virtualenv whatever` (this will create a folder `whatever` inside your current folder.
Then `cd` to it and type bin/activate to enter this virtual environment.
From there try again your `pip install` command.

Might help

UPDATE :
You might try to use the suggested solutions available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388519/problems-with-pip-install-numpy-runtimeerror-broken-toolchain-cannot-link-a)

To sumup, try to add `export ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future` inside `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Basically, virtualenv is a good way to go. To install it on a mac (no ``apt-get``), you can follow this [post](http://jamie.curle.io/blog/installing-pip-virtualenv-and-virtualenvwrapper-on-os-x/). However, the update in the OP suggests that there might be an issue with the C compiler, which needs to be solved as well.

Comment: @sthzg I think its definitely an issue with the compiler as well. I just tried to command export ARCHFLAGS in the bash_profile as well as with a module (numpy this time, another module that doesn't install for me): sudo ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install --upgrade numpy. And unfortunately, I got another error: Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" etc....

Comment: @user3736169 in the previous [link i gave you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388519/problems-with-pip-install-numpy-runtimeerror-broken-toolchain-cannot-link-a), some people explain that they had to just open XCode one type and accept the aggreement as this suggested : `I simply had to open XCode and accept the agreement and let it install the tools.` might help you too.

Answer (score -1):

This question comes first in Google, but the [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/python-pip-install-gives-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-c) one actually worked:

```
pip install -U setuptools

pip install ez_setup
```