# "pip install unroll": "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python, pip, package, installation

I'm trying to install some packages with `pip`.

But `pip install unroll` gives me

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
> C:\Users\MARKAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-wa7uco0k\unroll\

How can I solve this?

Comment: What version of windows are you running? As @hackndo says, this is a permissions problem, try running the same again with the command prompt as administrator.

Comment: @alaye Do you have a stack trace for the error?

Comment: I recommend everyone to follow this url for installing https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-django-web-framework-on-ubuntu-14-04 rather than following the official site. I got the same error but when I followed the methods in this site it worked.

Comment: use `sudo pip `

Comment: 07/2021 answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68458775/8718377

Answer (score 230):

**About the error code**

According to [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/errno.html):

> This module makes available standard errno system symbols. The value of each symbol is the corresponding integer value. **The names and descriptions are borrowed from linux/include/errno.h**, which should be pretty all-inclusive.

Error code 1 is defined in `errno.h` and means `Operation not permitted`.

**About your error**

Your [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) do not appear to be installed. Just follow the [`Installation Instructions`](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/) from the PyPI website.

If it's already installed, try

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

If it's already up to date, check that the module ez_setup is not missing. If it is, then

```
pip install ez_setup
```

Then try again

```
pip install unroll
```

If it's still not working, maybe pip didn't install/upgrade setup_tools properly so you might want to try

```
easy_install -U setuptools
```

And again

```
pip install unroll
```

Comment: I have the same problem and that did not fix it.

Comment: I have the same issue on windows and it is still not working

Comment: I get the same error when running in command window running as administrator. I also get the same error when I run pip install ez_setup as suggested as a fix to the first error. Any additional assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hopefully this will be indexed and returned if someone searches for it... This resolved my issue when trying to install `pylint`. `lazy-object-proxy` was  failing to be installed: "`error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'examples'`" "`Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1`". Updating `setuptools` fixed it.

Comment: Had this problem on ubuntu; this mostly worked. I needed to do: `sudo apt-get install python-setuptools` followed by `sudo easy_install -U setuptools`

Comment: Tried running with sudo as a workaround and it worked

Comment: `pip install --upgrade pip` was also epic

Comment: `pip install ez_setup` was the solution for me :)

Comment: Perfectly worked. Given Permission error, hence just add "sudo -H" i.e sudo -H pip install ez_setup

Comment: `pip install --upgrade setuptools --user python` worked for me (https://stackoverflow.com/a/36996892/4465464)

Comment: I tried upgrading pip without success. So I then tried this solution. When trying to install unroll via pip, I get the following error: `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/5v/vpmg1hf51cv8cxvkhw5t7s000000gn/T/pip-install-rn3yl6lt/unroll/`. Any ideas what to try next? In case it's relevant, my actual use case is trying to install mySQL for mac OSX as suggested [here](https://github.com/worldveil/dejavu/blob/master/INSTALLATION.md).

Comment: didn't help for me.

Comment: @VineeshTP Did you figure it out ?

Comment: @pixis: I was tried to install 'textract' . I could n't run textract on windows but, in Mac it is working fine. Then tried with 'tika' for reading pdf . It is good.

Comment: I faced the same issue while installing `mysqlclient` on *Ubuntu 22.04*. This is what I had to install in addition in order to get going `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev libpython3-dev build-essential`

Answer (score 94):

Here's a little guide explaining a little bit how I usually install new packages on Python + Windows. It seems you're using Windows paths, so this answer will stick to that particular SO:

- I never use a system-wide Python installation. I only use virtualenvs, and usually I try to have the latest version of 2.x & 3.x.
- My first attempt is always doing `pip install package_i_want` in some of my Visual Studio command prompts. What Visual Studio command prompt? Well, ideally the Visual Studio which matches the one which was used to build Python. For instance, let's say your Python installation says `Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:40:30) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`. The version of Visual Studio used to compile Python can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676763/what-version-of-visual-studio-is-python-on-my-computer-compiled-with/2676904#2676904), so v1500 means I'd be using vs2008 x64 command prompt
- If the previous step failed for some reason I just try using `easy_install package_i_want`
- If the previous step failed for some reason I go to [gohlke website](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#distribute) and I check whether my package is available over there. If it's so, I'm lucky, I just download it into my virtualenv and then I just go to that location using a command prompt and I do `pip install package_i_want.whl`
- If the previous step didn't succeed I'll just try to build the wheel myself and once it's generated I'll try to install it with `pip install package_i_want.whl`

Now, if we focus in your specific problem, where you're having a hard time installing the [unroll](https://github.com/Zulko/unroll) package. It seems the fastest way to install it is doing something like this:

- `git clone https://github.com/Zulko/unroll`
- `cd unroll && python setup.py bdist_wheel`
- Copy the generated unroll-0.1.0-py2-none-any.whl file from the created dist folder into your virtualenv.
- `pip install unroll-0.1.0-py2-none-any.whl`

That way it will install without any problems. To check it really works, just login into the Python installation and try `import unroll`, it shouldn't complain.

One last note: This method works almost 99% of the time, and sometimes you'll find some pip packages which are specific to Unix or Mac OS X, in that case, when that happens I'm afraid the best way to get a Windows version is either posting some issues to the main developers or having some fun by yourself porting to Windows (typically a few hours if you're not lucky) :)

Comment: What do you mean by "build the wheel myself"? Could you give an example please? Cheers

Comment: Sry its not working for me, it says unroll-0.1.0-py2-none-any.whl is not supported wheel on this platform

Comment: To build a wheel: 'pip install wheel', then 'python setup.py bdist_wheel'. If bdist_wheel is not found, go into the setup.py file and comment out 'from distutils.core import setup' and import the following instead: 'from setuptools import setup'. Then cd into the dist folder and 'pip install wheel_name.whl'

Comment: Try to update setuptools through pip first `pip install --upgrade setuptools`. This will help in most of the cases.

Comment: I followed your steps of : git clone
But no luck. I'm trying to install django channels. Still getting the same error.

Failed building wheel for cryptography
Could not build wheels for cryptography which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Answer (score 76):

It was resolved after upgrading pip:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
pip install "package-name"
```

Comment: Had the same problem and upgrading pip solved the issue for me as well.

Comment: after doing 

    python -m pip install --upgrade pip

I got 

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main

As if it broke my pip?

Comment: Yes, this worked for me as well while none of the solution offers above has solved the problem in my case.

Comment: If you use `pipenv` make sure to update pipenv using `pip install --upgrade pipenv` instead.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me when trying to install flask-sqlalchemy in a virtual environment.

Comment: You can use `python -m pip install "package-name"` as the second command to make sure you're using the same `pip` in both commands.

Comment: That fixed my issue. Thanks!

Comment: This should be accepted as an answer. tx

Comment: I get this exact error when I try to upgrade PIP. So do I need to upgrade PIP to be able to upgrade PIP? OMG...

Answer (score 35):

I got stuck exactly with the same error with `psycopg2`. It looks like I skipped a few steps while installing Python and related packages.

1. `sudo apt-get install python-dev libpq-dev`
2. Go to your virtual env
3. `pip install psycopg2`

(In your case you need to replace `psycopg2` with the package you have an issue with.)

It worked seamlessly.

Comment: Installed those packages on Ubuntu, the issue persists. Maybe if you shared your process, we could install the relevant packages on our systems.

Comment: Hi Nagev, sorry, I didn't look at my messages. hope you figured it out. I followed standard python installation process. I will be installing on a new VM shortly and will get back.

Comment: I sorted it out a long time ago @SriSri just using "apt-get install", thanks.

Comment: @SriSri I too am getting the error for psycopg2. Is sudo apt-get install python-dev libpq-dev supposed to be done outside the venv? And do you know what the equivalent command for windows is? Thanks!

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python-dev` did the trick. Thank you. The obnoxious attitudes of other people who answered with invalid solutions is sickening.

Answer (score 24):

I got this same error while installing `mitmproxy` using `pip3`. The below command fixed this:

```
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
```

Answer (score 8):

- Download and install the `Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7` from https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=44266 - this package contains the compiler and set of system headers necessary for producing binary wheels for Python 2.7 packages.
- Open a command prompt in elevated mode (run as administrator)
- Firstly do `pip install ez_setup`
- Then do `pip install unroll` (It will start installing `numpy, music21, decorator, imageio, tqdm, moviepy, unroll`) # Please be patient for `music21` installation

Python 2.7.11 64 bit used

Comment: I just get the same error: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-QRMQDo/ez-setup/

Comment: @Nagev, what is the OS type you are working on? And is possible to post complete traceback link?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 16.04. It's too long, I've only added the end, when doing "pip install ez_setup":

        return eval(compiled_marker, environment)
      File "<environment marker>", line 1, in <module>
    NameError: name 'sys_platform' is not defined
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-NRUrS7/HTML/

Answer (score 5):

Other way:

```
sudo apt-get install python-psycopg2 python-mysqldb
```

Comment: That's the only solution on this page that worked for me so far. I used "apt-get install python-pycurl". However, doing "pip install http://www.decalage.info/files/HTML.py-0.04.zip" brings back the issue. So pip install is still needed...

Comment: For me I did realize that I had not installed an important dependency which is python-mysqldb. After installing the two it worked just like magic. :)

Comment: I am getting this error: `Package 'python-psycopg2' has no installation candidate`. I tried updating: `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 5):

It's a dependency issue.

I tried running the following commands helped me sorting out the dependencies, in my case the dependency was

> grpcio

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip

python3 -m pip install --upgrade setuptools

pip3 install --no-cache-dir  --force-reinstall -Iv grpcio==1.36.1

pip3 install pulsar-client==2.7.0
```

remember you must have python3 installed in your system.

Answer (score 4):

First try:

```
pip install unroll
```

> For sure not work :)

Then Try:

```
pip2 install unroll
```

Still get error Try:

```
pip3 install unroll
```

If `pip3` Worked then suggest to change configuration to use `pip3` as `pip` because you will get a lot of issues as the modern now is **Python3 = pip3** if you execute a script files.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue when installing the "Twisted" library and solved it by running the following command on Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus):

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools python-dev build-essential
```

Answer (score 4):

```bash
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
```

```
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
```

To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with `-m pip` instead of running pip directly.

Use `python3 -m pip "command"`, eg:

```bash
python3 -m pip install --user pyqt5
```

Answer (score 4):

For me this worked

```
python3 -m pip3 install -U pip
```

you can also try

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

**The problem was**:

`pyparsing 2.2` was already installed and my `requirements.txt` was trying to install `pyparsing 2.0.1` which throw this error

**Context**: I was using virtualenv, and it seems the 2.2 came from my global OS Python `site-packages`, but even with `--no-site-packages` flag (now by default in last virtualenv) the 2.2 was still present. Surely because I installed Python from their website and it added Python libraries to my `$PATH`.

Maybe a `pip install --ignore-installed` would have worked.

**Solution**: as I needed to move forwards, I just removed the `pyparsing==2.0.1` from my `requirements.txt`.

Comment: What is this requirements.txt file? I don't seem to have it on my Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: it is a list of packages to install. see https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/1.1/requirements.html

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same error code when trying to install a Python module with pip.
@Hackndo noted that the documentation indicate a security issue.

Based on that answer, my problem was solved by running the pip install command with sudo prefixed:

```
sudo pip install python-mpd2
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried all of the above with no success. I then updated my Python version from 2.7.10 to 2.7.13, and it resolved the problems that I was experiencing.

Comment: And how did you upgrade, manually downloading and building? I'd prefer not to do that as I like it to be managed. When I try "sudo apt-get install python2.7" it tells me that I'm already using the latest version (2.7.12).

Comment: @Nagev What version are you on right now? Here is a link that gives instructions on how to specify version. I don't remember exactly how I did it. [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101591/how-do-i-install-the-latest-python-2-7-x-or-3-x-on-ubuntu)

Comment: I'm still on 2.7.12, my original issue is resolved, thanks for the link. I still find that installing via the repositories leads to fewer issues down the road.

Answer (score 2):

That means some packages in pip are old or not correctly installed.

1. Try checking version and then upgrading pip.Use auto remove if that works.
2. If the pip command shows an error all the time for any command or it freezes, etc.
3. The best solution is to uninstall it or remove it completely.
4. Install a fresh pip and then update and upgrade your system.
5. I have given a solution to installing pip fresh here - *[python: can't open file get-pip.py error 2] no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39790923/python-cant-open-file-get-pip-py-error-2-no-such-file-or-directory/43084606#43084606)*

Comment: To upgrade pip to the latest version: python -m pip install --upgrade pip

Answer (score 2):

### If `pip install --upgrade setuptools` did not work, try the following instead (python3):

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

It resolved the issue and now I am able to install `unroll` via:

```
python3 -m pip install unroll
```

Answer (score 1):

next installation helps me:

```
pip3 install cython
```

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the .whl file from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and then did:

```
pip install scipy-0.19.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
```

Note that the version you need to use (win32/win_amd-64) depends on the version of Python and not that of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo xcodebuild -license
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem using virtualenvs (with pipenv) on my new development setup.

I could only solve it by upgrading the psycopg2 version from 2.6.2 to 2.7.3. 
More information is at https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/594

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading Python to version 3 fixed my problem. Nothing else did.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with the same error message but on Ubuntu 16.04  LTS (Xenial Xerus) instead:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-w71uo1rg/poster/

I tested all the solutions provided above and none of them worked for me. I read the full TraceBack and found out I had to create the virtual environment with Python version 2.7 instead (the default one uses Python 3.5 instead):

```
virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.7 my_venv
```

Once I activated it, I run `pip install unirest` successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was able to fix by doing the following.

Windows Python needs Visual C++ libraries installed via the SDK to build code, such as via setuptools.extension.Extension or numpy.distutils.core.Extension. For example, building f2py modules in Windows with Python requires Visual C++ SDK as installed above. On Linux and Mac, the C++ libraries are installed with the compiler.

https://www.scivision.co/python-windows-visual-c++-14-required/

Answer (score 0):

try on linux:

```
sudo apt install python-pip python-bluez libbluetooth-dev libboost-python-dev libboost-thread-dev libglib2.0-dev bluez bluez-hcidump
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it on Centos 7 by using:

```
sudo yum install libcurl-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on my Win10 PC with different packages and tried everything mentioned so far.

Finally solved it by **disabling Comodo Auto-Containment**.

Since nobody has mentioned it yet, I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Following below command worked for me

```
[root@sandbox ~]# pip install google-api-python-client==1.6.4
```

Answer (score 0):

### Methods to solve setup.pu egg_info issue when updating setuptools or not other methods doesnot works.

1. If **CONDA** version of the library is available to install use conda instead of pip.
2. Clone the library repo and then try installation by `pip install -e .` or by `python setup.py install`

Answer (score 0):

upgrading python's version did the work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have just encountered the same problem when trying to `pip install -e .` a new repo. I did not notice that the contents of `setup.py` haven't been saved properly and I was effectively running the command with an empty `setup.py`.

Hence you may experience the same error message if the `setup.py` of the target package is either empty or malformed.

Answer (score -1):

Also, check that you have the package name spelled correctly. If you have the wrong name or misspelled, you will get this error.