# sudo pip install setuptools --upgrade error

Tags: python-2.7

I am doing `pip install setuptools --upgrade` but getting error below

```
Installing collected packages: setuptools
  Found existing installation: setuptools 1.1.6
    Uninstalling setuptools-1.1.6:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 726, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 746, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 299, in move
    copytree(src, real_dst, symlinks=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 208, in copytree
    raise Error, errors
Error: [('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py', '/tmp/pip-rV15My-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-rV15My-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc', '/tmp/pip-rV15My-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-rV15My-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py', '/tmp/pip-rV15My-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-rV15My-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc', '/tmp/pip-rV15My-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-rV15My-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib', '/tmp/pip-rV15My-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-rV15My-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib'")]
```

What am I missing? I tried sudo pip install also but didn't help.

Comment: Please delete that whole output and re-add it using **code formatting** (the **`{}`**-button in your question editor or CTRL+K), it's horribly hard to read without formatting (and the blockquote-button you used already destroyed the original structure)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try to upgrade manually:

```
pip uninstall setuptools
pip install setuptools
```

If it doesn't work, try:
    `pip install --upgrade setuptools --user python`

As you can see, the operation didn't get appropriate privilege：

`[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-rV15My-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc'")`

Comment: `pip install --upgrade setuptools --user python` works perfectly for me

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem but with a different error, and different resolution. (My search for a solution led me here, so I'm posting my details here in case it helps.)

TL;DR: if upgrading `setuptools` in a Python virtual environment appears to work, but reports `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`, try deactivating and reactivating the virtual environment before continuing, e.g.:

```
    source myenv/bin/activate
    pip install --upgrade setuptools
    deactivate
    source myenv/bin/activate
     :
```

### Long version

I'm in the process of upgrading Python version and libraries for a long-running project.  I use a python virtual environment for development and testing.  Host system is MacOS 10.11.5 (El Capitan). I've discovered that `pip` needs to be updated after the virtual environment is created (apparently due to some recent `pypa` TLS changes as of 2018-04), so my initial setup looks like this (having installed the latest version of the Python 2.7 series using the downloadable MacOS installer):

```
    virtualenv myenv -p python2.7
    source myenv/bin/activate
    curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
    python get-pip.py
```

So far, so good :)  My problem comes when I try to run:

```
    pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

The installation appears to work OK, but then I get an error message, thus:

```
    Collecting setuptools
      Using cached setuptools-39.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Installing collected packages: setuptools
      Found existing installation: setuptools 0.6rc11
        Uninstalling setuptools-0.6rc11:
          Successfully uninstalled setuptools-0.6rc11
    Successfully installed setuptools-39.0.1
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/graham/workspace/github/gklyne/annalist/anenv/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
        sys.exit(main())
      File "/Users/graham/workspace/github/gklyne/annalist/anenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 248, in main
        return command.main(cmd_args)
      File "/Users/graham/workspace/github/gklyne/annalist/anenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 252, in main
        pip_version_check(session)
      File "/Users/graham/workspace/github/gklyne/annalist/anenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/outdated.py", line 102, in pip_version_check
        installed_version = get_installed_version("pip")
      File "/Users/graham/workspace/github/gklyne/annalist/anenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 838, in get_installed_version
        working_set = pkg_resources.WorkingSet()
      File "/Users/graham/workspace/github/gklyne/annalist/anenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 644, in __init__
        self.add_entry(entry)
      File "/Users/graham/workspace/github/gklyne/annalist/anenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 700, in add_entry
        for dist in find_distributions(entry, True):
      File "/Users/graham/workspace/github/gklyne/annalist/anenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1949, in find_eggs_in_zip
        if metadata.has_metadata('PKG-INFO'):
      File "/Users/graham/workspace/github/gklyne/annalist/anenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1463, in has_metadata
        return self.egg_info and self._has(self._fn(self.egg_info, name))
      File "/Users/graham/workspace/github/gklyne/annalist/anenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1823, in _has
        return zip_path in self.zipinfo or zip_path in self._index()
      File "/Users/graham/workspace/github/gklyne/annalist/anenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1703, in zipinfo
        return self._zip_manifests.load(self.loader.archive)
      File "/Users/graham/workspace/github/gklyne/annalist/anenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1643, in load
        mtime = os.stat(path).st_mtime
    OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/graham/workspace/github/gklyne/annalist/anenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg'
```

Note that the installation appears to complete successfully, followed by the `OSError` exception, which appears to be an attempt to access the old setuptools.  Despite the error message, `pip` seems to work just fine for installing new packages, but my local `setup.py` fails to find its dependencies; e.g.:

```
    $ python setup.py install
    running install
      :
     (lots of build messages)
      :
    Installed /Users/graham/workspace/github/gklyne/annalist/anenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client-1.2-py2.7.egg
    Processing dependencies for oauth2client==1.2
    Searching for httplib2>=0.8
    Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/httplib2/
    Couldn't find index page for 'httplib2' (maybe misspelled?)
    Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
    Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
    No local packages or working download links found for httplib2>=0.8
    error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('httplib2>=0.8')
```

But if I use pip to install the same dependency ('httplib2>=0.8'), it works fine, and I can re-run `setup.py` without any problems.

At this point I'm guessing that the difference between running `setup.py` and `pip` is that the virtual environment is somehow hanging onto some old `setuptools` files, but `pip` comes with its own copy.  So after upgrading setuptools and getting the `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` message, I deactivate and reactivate the virtual environment, thus:

```
    deactivate
    source myenv/bin/activate
```

and, *viola*, `setup.py` seems to work fine!