# Python distribute installation Mac

Tags: python, module, distribute

I am trying to install distribute module one my mac. I tried pip install distribute and got the error

```
***"""***

Collecting distribute
  Using cached distribute-0.7.3.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/hj/gz4x7_lj5r9_shsmq40r2y180000gn/T/pip-build-10mpi66y/distribute/setuptools/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
        from setuptools.extension import Extension, Library
      File "/private/var/folders/hj/gz4x7_lj5r9_shsmq40r2y180000gn/T/pip-build-10mpi66y/distribute/setuptools/extension.py", line 5, in <module>
        from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
      File "/private/var/folders/hj/gz4x7_lj5r9_shsmq40r2y180000gn/T/pip-build-10mpi66y/distribute/setuptools/dist.py", line 7, in <module>
        from setuptools.command.install import install
      File "/private/var/folders/hj/gz4x7_lj5r9_shsmq40r2y180000gn/T/pip-build-10mpi66y/distribute/setuptools/command/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
        from setuptools.command import install_scripts
      File "/private/var/folders/hj/gz4x7_lj5r9_shsmq40r2y180000gn/T/pip-build-10mpi66y/distribute/setuptools/command/install_scripts.py", line 3, in <module>
        from pkg_resources import Distribution, PathMetadata, ensure_directory
      File "/private/var/folders/hj/gz4x7_lj5r9_shsmq40r2y180000gn/T/pip-build-10mpi66y/distribute/pkg_resources.py", line 1518, in <module>
        register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
    AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/hj/gz4x7_lj5r9_shsmq40r2y180000gn/T/pip-build-10mpi66y/distribute/

***"""***
```

I tried the program "distribute_setup.py" and by running "python3.6 install_distribute.py" but got the error "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: SSL is required"

I tried updating urllib but it said it was correct. any recommendations?

Comment: Distribute went the way of the norwegian blue a long time ago.  Why are you trying to install that?

Answer (score 2):

The 'Distribute' module is deprecated. Its development is now part of 'Setuptools'. So, if you install 'Setuptools' you should get 'Distribute'. See:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute/0.7.3
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute/0.6.49

The first link to PyPI even says that 'Distribute':

> This package is a simple compatibility layer that installs Setuptools 0.7+.

So, you might have better luck by trying to install or update 'Setuptools'. To get more into it, I think there is a problem with either:

1. Your pip version
2. Your Python version
3. Or, your 'Setuptools'

This is the line that I am interested in:

```
AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
```

This error seems like something is trying to use a newly added feature that doesn't exist in the old version of a file. So, you probably need to update pip or 'Setuptools'.

Try:

- [using pip3: module "importlib._bootstrap" has no attribute "SourceFileLoader"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44761958/using-pip3-module-importlib-bootstrap-has-no-attribute-sourcefileloader)

Specifically, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47278208/9347694

Also try,

- [sudo pip install setuptools --upgrade error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36996629/sudo-pip-install-setuptools-upgrade-error)

Seems like others experienced this issue after installing Python 3.6. Are you sure you are using pip3? Is pip updated? Do you have 'Seyuptools' installed properly?