# pip install returns code 1 error with saga_python. Any ideas?

Tags: python, pip, python-3.5

I am trying to install saga-python (package for SAGA GIS) and cmd python keeps returning the same error: python setup.py egg_info failed with code 1 in C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-7uieglh9\saga-python. Any ideas why it occurs?

Also, tried a few tips from this question's answers: 
[Python pip install gives "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/python-pip-install-gives-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-c-) not working either.

Version is 3.5.2 and setuptools and ez_setup are allright. 
Tried with easy_install as well. No results either, sais that the syntax is invalid.

Also tried with virtualenv and http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/. Error is caused by two different Python versions: 2.7 and 3.5.2. I cannot uninstall 2.7 (shell for some GIS software), but I need to make it work somehow.

Answer (score 2):

This package only for python 2.X. See [issue](https://github.com/radical-cybertools/saga-python/issues/399)