# python: can't open file get-pip.py error 2] no such file or directory

Tags: python, pip, installation

When I am trying to execute this in CMD

```
python get-pip.py
```

I am getting this error:

> ```
> python: can't open file get-pip.py error 2] no such file or directory
> ```

While the file store in (get-pip.py)

> C:\Python27\Tools\Scripts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to either `cd` into folder with script (`cd "C:\Python27\Tools\Scripts"`) or add this folder to your PATH variable.

Answer (score 15):

For Linux/Mac, you can go for

```
curl 'https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py' > get-pip.py && sudo python get-pip.py
```

1. Fetching installer
2. Executing file with superuser access

Answer (score 0):

Go to this link - https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/

For me it installed in

`vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip`

So there is a mistake in the post as the command 
`pip --help`

will not work.

`vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant$ pip --help
-bash: /usr/bin/pip: No such file or directory`

But you still have pip installed.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Just open C drive than click on Users > (Your Username)> AppData\Local\Programs\Python>Just copy the previous step then follow below points:

open My PC>Right Click > Properties>Advance Settings> Environmental>Path>Edit>New>then open that folder which is been opened above then open Script(folder) and click the path and copy
and paste it in New then ok>ok and here we go