# Trying to install pip for python 3.6

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pip

I was following the instructions for installing the AWS Command Line interface on macOS, and I got as far as running `$ curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py` and was presented with a large block of code which I suppose installed pip.

When I run the next command `$ python3 get-pip.py --user`, I get an error that says `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'get-pip.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Has anyone encountered this? The instructions I'm following are here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-install-macos.html#awscli-install-osx-path

Comment: was the file get-pip.py present in your current directory or any environment variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python: can't open file get-pip.py error 2\] no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39790923/python-cant-open-file-get-pip-py-error-2-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Docs at AWS have a bad advice. The correct command is

```
curl -o get-pip.py https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
```

See https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py