# What is [Errno 2] in pip installation?

Tags: python, pip, file-not-found

I am setting up [pip using the official documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/) on an Ubuntu 22.04 LTS system, and when I execute the `python get-pip.py` command, I get an error message stating:

```
python3: can't open file '/home/usr/get-pip.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I thought it was an error on my part because `python` commands don't work in Linux distros and I aliased the python3 command:

```bash
alias python='python3'
```

The problem persisted. A quick Google Search led me to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48122742/18533523) and my error was solved.

Afterwards, I did some digging on what [Errno 2] is but all of the material I encountered was hyperfocused on solving this error and not what causes it.

Comment: Here's the [error codes manual](https://www.daemon-systems.org/man/errno.2.html). If you scroll down, ERRNO (error number) 2 is simply the number for a missing file or directory.

Comment: Did you actually download `get-pip.py`? That command only works if you have a copy of that file in your current working directory; clearly you don't.

Comment: `sudo apt install python3-pip` probably works; and is probably the better solution, since that matches a system-installed Python with a system-installed Pip.

Comment: Beside the point, but that alias doesn't affect the command name `python3`, it's for the command name `python`.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are asking? The message you have provided already says what errno 2 means: "No such file or directory", in your case specifically when trying to open get-pip.py (i.e. Python can’t open the file because there is no such file).

Comment: Cross-posted: https://askubuntu.com/q/1483534/158442 https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/754865/70524

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not pip-specific. It's documented in [`errno`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/errno.html), specifically:

> [`errno.ENOENT`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/errno.html#errno.ENOENT)
>
> No such file or directory. This error is mapped to the exception [`FileNotFoundError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#FileNotFoundError).

If you didn't know to look for "No such file or directory", you could use [`os.strerror()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.strerror) or [`errno.errorcode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/errno.html#errno.errorcode):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.strerror(2)
'No such file or directory'
>>> 
>>> import errno
>>> errno.errorcode[2]
'ENOENT'
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard linux error codes can be found by running `man 3 errno` or referencing [errno(3) — Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html).

```
   ENOENT          No such file or directory (POSIX.1-2001).

                   Typically, this error results when a specified pathname does not exist, or one  of
                   the components in the directory prefix of a pathname does not exist, or the speci‐
                   fied pathname is a dangling symbolic link.
```

It means what it says: the file doesn't exist.

Python commands *do* work on linux and there was no need to alias `python` here. You ran `python get-pip.py` and python told you that it couldn't find `get-pip.py`. You ran from the current working directory `/home/usr/` but python tried to be friendly and show the absolute path of the non-existent file.

The instructions told you to download get-pip.py, change to the download directory and then run the command. You must have missed one of those steps.

The solution that worked for you downloaded get-pip.py into the current working directory and executed it. That's why it worked. It may not have been so wise to `sudo` first as you risk overwriting your platform-installed python as opposed to installing a local python.