# Python pip install fails with error

Tags: python, windows, windows-10, python-3.5, yajl

I have been trying to install *yajl>=0.3.5* package and i get the following error. This happens for only this specific package and not for others i am currently using. The command is as follows.

```
                         pip install yajl>=0.3.5
```

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\ANURAG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-epamw9qh\yajl\

Alternatively

I know there is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/python-pip-install-gives-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-c) asked and have tried all specified solutions in the mentioned question. Here are my findings.

1) I have successfully installed setuptools,upgraded them and also installed ez_setup. `pip install yajl>=0.3.5` gives the same error as above even after this.

2) I have downloaded the source code of *yajl>=0.3.5* and tried the following command.

```
        cd yajl && python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

the error i get is as below.

> Collecting yajl>=0.3.5
>
> ```
>  Using cached yajl-0.3.5.tar.gz
>   Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "C:\Users\ANURAG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\yajl\setup.py",
> ```
>
> line 64, in 
>           subprocess.call(['git', 'submodule', 'update',])
>         File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 560, in call
>           with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
>         File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 950, in **init**
>           restore_signals, start_new_session)
>         File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 1220, in _execute_child
>           startupinfo)
>       FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
>
> ---
>
> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\ANURAG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\yajl\

PS: I am using windows 10.

Comment: Hm, this package is quite old. Version 0.3.5 is the latest version and it is from 2010.