# Cannot pip install scipy, mlxtend and math libraries

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, scipy

I am using python 3.5 on windows 10. I am not able to install some libraries like scipy, mlxtend and math.

I have installed and upgraded setuptools and ez_setup following this answer 
[Python pip install gives "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/python-pip-install-gives-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-c)

## When I try to pip install scipy and mlxtend I get the following error:

`NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found`

## And when I try to install math I get the following error:

```
  Using cached Math-0.5.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\raisa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-e23g412r\math\setup.py", line 2, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError("Package 'Math' must not be downloaded from pypi")
RuntimeError: Package 'Math' must not be downloaded from pypi

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\raisa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-e23g412r\math\
```

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, you'll want to locate the [unofficial binaries here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and download the appropriate `.whl` files for the packages you're wanting to install. Use `pip` to install and upgrade `wheel` and `setuptools` then do `pip install the_name_of_the_file.whl`

so altogether, assuming you want to install matplotlib and the .whl file is in your current directory...

```
pip install wheel
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install matplotlib‑1.5.3‑cp35‑cp35m‑win32.whl
```