# Unable to Install beautifulsoup on Windows 8.1

Tags: python, windows-8.1, python-3.6

I am unable to install beautifulsoup module

Error:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install beautifulsoup
Collecting beautifulsoup
  Using cached BeautifulSoup-3.2.1.tar.gz
   Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\surabhis\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-tdxcdfig\beautifulsou
p\setup.py", line 22
    print "Unit tests have failed!"
                                  ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\username
\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-tdxcdfig\beautifulsoup\
```

I followed the work arounds specified at 
[Python pip install gives "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/python-pip-install-gives-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-c)

pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install ez_setup followed by retry of module installation.

However, it is still not working. I am using cmd as administrator.

OS : Windows 8.1 Pro
Python : 3.6.0

Comment: Try `pip install beautifulsoup4`, as instructed in the official site: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what version you were using but I just used the syntax you provided because I couldn't install via Windows 8.1, but used "beautifulsoup4" (not "beautifulsoup") and it worked!

Answer (score -1):

I am a novice. Since there is no response I thought I will respond with this. Under Windows 7 I found that python print command does not work without parenthesis around the print argument. So may be you can change the script so that its print commands have these parentheses.

Comment: Actually, print is a function in python 3. You will not see language implementation details that are specified directly in the spec change across operating systems like that--doing so would be a bug in the interpreter, and should be exceedingly rare. See [source](http://www.wellho.net/resources/ex.php4?item=y300/print_3.py)