# Can't install mysql-python with pip on MacOS 10.12.4

Tags: python, macos, pip

Following error recieved when running `pip install mysql-python`

```
Collecting mysql-python
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/b_/xh05hxwd0lzc3rm858jsypdc0000gn/T/pip-build-AWDYaP/mysql-python/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 53, in get_config
        libraries = [ dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith(compiler_flag("l")) ]
      File "setup_posix.py", line 8, in dequote
        if s[0] in "\"'" and s[0] == s[-1]:
    IndexError: string index out of range

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/b_/xh05hxwd0lzc3rm858jsypdc0000gn/T/pip-build-AWDYaP/mysql-python/
```

I followed the instructions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/python-pip-install-gives-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-c) post around reinstalling setuptools and I have reinstalled Python from https://www.python.org/

`which -a python` gives

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

The error seems to have occurred since installing MacOS 10.12.4 update

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Solved with this

```
brew install mysql
pip install MySQL-python
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This was driving me nuts. Actually I had to do both yours and the other person: brew unlink mysql-connector-c and then brew install mysql

Comment: Add a `brew link mysql` after that ^

Comment: I made sure that mysql is installed and linked, 
and then run pip install MySQL-python
and still same error

Answer (score 14):

If you still failed with something like "Failed building wheel for mysql-python", try

```
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib pip install mysql-python
```

which works like a charm for me.

Comment: Thank you! Saved me lots of hours!

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much! Saved me hours as well :)

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, thank you so much!!

Comment: Saved my day, too.

Comment: Saved my final grade project too.

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me (macOS Mojave 10.14.2):

```
brew install mysql@5.7
brew link --force mysql@5.7
brew install mysql-client
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib pip install mysql-python
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what worked for me. Also dealing with Mojave.

Comment: Thanks, saved me a lot of time. Worked on macOS Mojave.

Answer (score 4):

If you are like me and installed mysql from source in mac, then forget who are suggest to use brew - your machine already has mysql-connector-c. If you did brew install mysql-connector-c, do brew uninstall mysql-connector-c and try pip install mysql-python again (Python 3).

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
    brew install mysql@5.7
    brew link --force mysql@5.7
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix this we should edit mysql_config file.

For this, issue the command:

```
vi `which mysql_config`
```

This will open up the `mysql_config` in vi editor.

Press `i` to be in insert mode

Now find lines

```
# Create options 
libs="-L$pkglibdir"
libs="$libs -l "
```

for me it is on line 118.  The above lines should be changed to

```
# Create options 
libs="-L$pkglibdir"
libs="$libs -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto"
```

Now press `esc` button to exit from the insert mode and save the added content
by issuing command`:wq` in vi editor.

Now try to reinstalling the `MySQL-Python` module using pip.

Note it is assumed that `mysql` and `openssl` are installed

Comment: This solution was the only one that worked for me.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked:

```
brew install mysql-connector-c 
pip install MySQL-python
pip install mysql-connector
```