# error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1 on Mac for pip install MySQL-python

Tags: python, mysql, installation, mysql-python

I need to install MySQL-python through (pip install MySQL-python) on Mac due to this import error:

ImportError: No module named MySQLdb

But there is this error during pip install MySQL-python:

```
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7
cc -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes 
-Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -arch i386 
-arch x86_64 -pipe -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) 
-D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/local/opt/mysql-client/include/mysql 
-I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7
-c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/_mysql.o
_mysql.c:44:10: fatal error: 'my_config.h' file not found
#include "my_config.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

I tried different solutions provided by Stackoverflow such as:
    ["'cc' failed with exit status 1" error when install python library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697440/cc-failed-with-exit-status-1-error-when-install-python-library) or  [command 'cc' failed with exit status 1 on OSX High Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51343325/command-cc-failed-with-exit-status-1-on-osx-high-sierra) but still getting the same error.
Any suggestions or comments to resolve this?

Further info:

```
 (virt-env) m-c0:fz$ which python
   /usr/bin/python
 (virt-env) m-c0:fz$ which pip
  /usr/local/bin/pip
 (virt-env) m-c0:fz$ python --version
  Python 2.7.16

  export PATH="/usr/local/opt/cython/bin:$PATH"
  export PATH="/Users/zf/Library/Python/2.7/bin:$PATH"
  export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.18_1/bin
  export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql-client/bin:$PATH"
  export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
  export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have mysql C libraries installed on your Mac OS, there are multiple options to install it.

You can install it easy fi you have `brew` installed on your Mac OS, or google for other options to install the libs using your env.

More info

- [Can't install mysql-python with pip on MacOS 10.12.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43634584/cant-install-mysql-python-with-pip-on-macos-10-12-4)
- https://ruddra.com/posts/install-mysqlclient-macos/
- https://medium.com/@MrWeeble/homebrew-on-mac-and-pythons-mysqlclient-ea44fa300e70

Comment: followed the steps on this link: https://ruddra.com/posts/install-mysqlclient-macos/ and it's resolved! THANKS!

Comment: The link is no longer available, do you still have the steps?

Comment: https://medium.com/@MrWeeble/homebrew-on-mac-and-pythons-mysqlclient-ea44fa300e70       this link helps!  Short answer, run "env LDFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" pip install mysqlclient==1.3.12"