# Issue with installing pysftp with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, pysftp

I am trying to install the module pysftp onto my Rapspberry Pi, but I get an error returned when

```
sudo pip install pysftp
```

is run.
This is the error I get:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-U1R0_9/pynacl

I have tried running `pip install --upgrade setuptools` but this does not fix the error.

My python version is 3.4.2, and my pip version is 9.0.1 (python 3.4) if that helps.

I hope I have provided enough information to be useful, I tried as much as I can but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Please, show more error trace

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python pip install gives "Command "python setup.py egg\_info" failed with error code 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/python-pip-install-gives-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-c)