# Unable to install gensim in python

Tags: python, gensim

I have problem installing gensim module. I installed numpy and scipy dependent modules successfully but was getting error while installing gensim.
I tried solutions given in [Python pip install gives "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/python-pip-install-gives-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-c)
but none of them worked.

Here is the error:

```
    >pip install --target="D:\python\packages" gensim
Collecting gensim
  Using cached gensim-2.3.0-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
Collecting scipy>=0.18.1 (from gensim)
  Using cached scipy-0.19.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\abcde\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-hu8lzsjz\scipy\setup.py", line 416, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "C:\Users\abcde\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-hu8lzsjz\scipy\setup.py", line 412, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 108, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 315, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 361, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 850, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1122, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1134, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 429, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 653, in easy_install
        not self.always_copy, self.local_index
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\package_index.py", line 636, in fetch_distribution
        dist = find(requirement)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\package_index.py", line 617, in find
        dist.download_location = self.download(dist.location, tmpdir)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\package_index.py", line 566, in download
        found = self._download_url(scheme.group(1), spec, tmpdir)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\package_index.py", line 805, in _download_url
        return self._attempt_download(url, filename)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\package_index.py", line 811, in _attempt_download
        headers = self._download_to(url, filename)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\package_index.py", line 726, in _download_to
        block = fp.read(bs)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 449, in read
        n = self.readinto(b)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 493, in readinto
        n = self.fp.readinto(b)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\socket.py", line 586, in readinto
        return self._sock.recv_into(b)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1002, in recv_into
        return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\ssl.py", line 865, in read
        return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\ssl.py", line 625, in read
        v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
    ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\abcde\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-hu8lzsjz\scipy\
```

Comment: Seems like your connection was closed

Comment: Can you please tell me what am I supposed to do now.

Answer (score 0):

The error text you've supplied indicates the actual problem is (a) involving the attempt to install `scipy`, on which gensim relies; (b) related to a broken HTTPS connection, indicating a problem with network connectivity (or something blocking the secure-connection).

Also, it's rare to need to specify a `--target` for `pip`; if your environment (reachable executables) is correctly set-up, you'd be able to just do `pip install gensim`. (And if you are installing to a non-default location, you may have issues later when your active environment isn't using the libraries you expected.)

Suggestions:

- check that you are able to access remote secure websites, like say the homepage of the PyPI repository which `pip` is using: `https://pypi.python.org/pypi`
- try again later; perhaps the network issues were transient
- try just `pip install scipy`
- consider using the `conda` distribution tool, which tends to be well-optimized for Windows installations. (I generally prefer the `miniconda` variant, which installs only the minimum set of things you request.)

Also, while Python, gensim, and related packages can work on Windows systems, note that most development/testing on such Python/NLP/ML open-source happens on Linux/OSX systems. As a result, there are often extra installation/configuration issues on Windows, and then there's usually less prior-documented troubleshooting from people who've previously hit the same issues. So if you have choice, such work often goes smoothest on Linux/Unix systems.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion gojomo, I will use conda distribution. But the doubt I have is I could install scipy succesfully using pip, any idea why is this error coming up again? I used -- target because I don't have permission to write on to C drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can install genism by two ways:
1. pip install -U genism

2.install easy_install 
then

```html
easy_install https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-19.2.tar.gz
```