# Installing rasa on Windows

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio, nlp, rasa-nlu

I am trying to install rasa on Windows 10.
I have installed Python 3.6 & pip.
When I am running `pip install rasa_nlu` I am getting the following error:

```
c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\include\pyconfig.h(222): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory

error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I have tried most of the solutions like reinstalling Microsoft redistributables, installing build tools etc. but none of them worked.

Comment: Looks like you need Microsoft Visual Studio for this install. Can you check if you have `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe` installed and in the path?

Comment: For users looking to install RASA now can simply run `pip install rasa` Both the NLU and Core are installed together now.

Answer (score 5):

I also faced the similar issue. Here's how I resolved it:

For a clean install of RASA NLU on a Windows machine with all other dependencies, I followed the following steps:

> - [Anaconda 3 64-bit Windows](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-2019.03-Windows-x86_64.exe)
> - [Install Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126&fixForIE=.exe)
> - [Visual C++ 14.0 x64](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145)

While installing Anaconda in: `C:\Anaconda3`, because installing it in `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3` would cause some Folder Lock problem while installing some pip packages.

[image]

Install [JDK](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk12-downloads-5295953.html) and [JRE](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html) both and set the JAVA_HOME environment variable as **JVM** is required for the Duckling Date Parser needed by RASA NLU.

[image]

Next, install the following packages in this order in administrative mode in Anaconda 3 command prompt:

> - **Spacy** – `pip install -U spacy`
> - **Spacy Large English language model** - `python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg`
> - **Link the model now**: `python -m spacy link en_core_web_lg en`
> - Fallback if the above fails:   If your network is blocking it, or is too slow to download the above model, fallback by downloading it
>     directly from its [GitHub
>     repo](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_lg-2.0.0/en_core_web_lg-2.0.0.tar.gz)
>     extract the tar.gz using 7z and do python setup.py install by
>     navigating into the directory.
> - **Scikit** – `pip install -U scikit-learn`
> - **Numpy** – `pip install -U numpy`
> - **Scipy Package** – `pip install -U scipy`
> - **Sklearn** – `pip install -U sklearn-crfsuite`
> - **Duckling** – `pip install -U duckling`
> - **Tensorflow as a component** - `pip install -U tensorflow`
> - **Latest version of RASA NLU** – `pip install -U rasa_nlu`

Check if RASA installed or not by pasting the following command in Anaconda command prompt:

`python -c "import rasa_nlu; print(rasa_nlu.__version__);"`

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer**:

Use a pre-compiled wheel bundle for the dependency failing to install. (This is an unofficial source so use at your own risk) [Download here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#distribute)  and do

```
pip install /path/to/bundle.whl
```

**Long Answer**:

I faced a similar problem while installing rasa_nlu and this is how I resolved it.

The major problem was in installing the Twisted package. I had tried installing redistributables and build tools and my final error looked like this-

```
c:\program files\python36\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory

    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.11.25503\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I then decided to follow the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39155105/3282822) which describes ways to handle python library installations in a fallback approach.

My final resolution was downloading the twisted wheel from the source mentioned above, install the package and continue with rasa installation.

```
pip install ./Twisted-17.9.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
pip install rasa_nlu
```

**Note**:

If you are really skeptic in using an unofficial source, follow the instructions in SF answer I shared earlier to build your own bundle and use that wheel for installation.

Answer (score 0):

To this date In order to have rasa (and **tensorflow**) working on your windows machine :

you need to lower your python version at least to **python 3.6**
you need to lower your **python-dateutil** to at least **2.8.0**
Steps Assuming that you already have PIP, Virtualenv installed, you must follow these steps:

Python older version: In order to install it, download an older version of python (i found one [here](http://software.oldversion.com/windows/python-3-1-1) )

Create a virtual env using that python version you have just installed. using the command mkvirtualenv --python=path_of_python_older_version\ name_of_env

Activate the env you have just created (WORKON name_of_env)

Now install an older version of python-dateutil using the command pip install python-dateutil==2.8.0

Now you can install rasa,using the command pip install rasa

Hope it helps