# error installing pymc3 package using pip or git

Tags: pip, pymc3

I am trying to install pymc3 using git follows

```
$ pip install git+https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3
```

I get the following error

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/hm/40wvfw514611psdffd2gfxdw0000gn/T/pip-6adU4q-build/
```

and using pip

```
$ pip install pymc3
```

I get the following error

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/hm/40wvfw514611psdffd2gfxdw0000gn/T/pip-build-GLYokK/pymc3/
```

I got the following error while updating `setuptools`

[image]

Comment: You may need to upgrade setuptools by doing `pip install --upgrade setuptools` and then try again with `pip install pymc3`

Answer (score 2):

Try to run:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

This is according to:

[Python pip install gives "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/python-pip-install-gives-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-c)

Comment: Error: [('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc', '/var/folders/hm/40wvfw514611psdffd2gfxdw0000gn/T/pip-ueE8hC-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted:

Comment: please see updated question for more info, thanks for your previous suggestion