# Error when I'm trying to install angr on OS X

Tags: python, macos, angr

When I try to install `angr` I get this error:

```
>> pip install angr


> Collecting angr
>       Using cached angr-7.7.9.21.tar.gz
>     Collecting ana (from angr)
>       Using cached ana-0.03.zip
>     Collecting bintrees (from angr)
>       Using cached bintrees-2.0.7.zip
>     Collecting cachetools (from angr)
>       Using cached cachetools-2.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>     Collecting capstone (from angr)
>       Using cached capstone-3.0.4.tar.gz
>     Collecting cooldict (from angr)
>       Using cached cooldict-1.02.tar.gz
>     Collecting dpkt-fix (from angr)
>       Using cached dpkt-fix-1.7.tar.gz
>     Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
>       File "/private/var/folders/sw/ccryj7_95wn7wc94w2nn1plw0000gn/T/pip-build-njcedr48/dpkt-fix/setup.py",
> line 4, in <module>
>         import dpkt
>       File "/private/var/folders/sw/ccryj7_95wn7wc94w2nn1plw0000gn/T/pip-build-njcedr48/dpkt-fix/dpkt/__init__.py",
> line 13, in <module>
>         import ah
>     ImportError: No module named 'ah'
>     
>     ----------------------------------------
>     Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in      /private/var/folders/sw/ccryj7_95wn7wc94w2nn1plw0000gn/T/pip-build-njcedr48/dpkt-fix/
```

Could you help to solve this problem?

```
OS X EI Captain 10.11.6
```

Comment: Fowllow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/python-pip-install-gives-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-c

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using Python 3.  `angr` depends upon the package [`dpkt-fix`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dpkt-fix/), which tries to import itself when installing, which fails in Python 3 because `dpkt-fix`'s code uses `import ah` (et alii) to mean `import .ah`, which only works in Python 2.

Solution: Use Python 2 instead.