# Getting errors when using pip to install pandas

Tags: python

I've been trying to install pandas using pip, but it always fails and gives me a giant wall of error text and this at the bottom:

```
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-2oyp61xi\pandas
```

Its getting pretty annoying and I would appreciate some help!

Comment: Try the answer for this similar question: [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/python-pip-install-gives-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**About the error code**

According to [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/errno.html):

> This module makes available standard errno system symbols. The value of each symbol is the corresponding integer value. **The names and descriptions are borrowed from linux/include/errno.h**, which should be pretty all-inclusive.

Error code 1 is defined in `errno.h` and means `Operation not permitted`.

**About your error**

Your [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) do not appear to be installed. Just follow the [`Installation Instructions`](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/) from the pypi website.

If it's already installed, try

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

If it's already up to date, check that the module ez_setup is not missing. If it is, then

```
pip install ez_setup
```

Then try again

```
pip install unroll
```

If it's still not working, maybe pip didn't install/upgrade setup_tools properly so you might want to try

```
easy_install -U setuptools
```

and again

```
pip install unroll
```