# How to install packages for django-1.11.8

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am getting erorr when installing modules using pip for python 2.7 after django-2 comes.

I am trying to install django_cron for django-1.11.8 and python-2.7 but I am getting the error-

```
      @functools.lru_cache()
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-JKhsAF/Django/
```

So how to install modules for python-2.7 and django-1.11.8 ????

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issues before, I found that you may need to update pip and setup tools, this according to excellent answer I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/python-pip-install-gives-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-c).

But the solution that worked for me is, I download loaded Django 1.10.5, then I was been able to install any package I want.