# Raspberry Pi Cannot Download Packages Using Pip

Tags: python, raspberry-pi2

I am having an issue downloading packages on my Raspberry Pi 2 using `pip`. When running `sudo pip install packageName`, the following is outputted:

```
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /home/pi/build/jsonschema
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Has the package installed successfully, or was there an error? The packages that I am trying to install are `piui` and `plotly`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python pip install gives "Command "python setup.py egg\_info" failed with error code 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/python-pip-install-gives-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-c)

Comment: Could you show some more debug messages? Either by doing `pip install --verbose packageName` or by doing `cat /root/.pip/pip.log`.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/JWXJpDCG