# Cannot install asyncmc [Version Issue]

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I have been trying to install asyncmc module via conda and I keep on getting error below. I am not able to figure out the exact issue.

```
 pip install asyncmc 

Collecting asyncmc
Using cached asyncmc-0.6.6.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-8yudAS/asyncmc/setup.py", line 18, in <module>
    long_description='\n\n'.join((read('README.md'), read('CHANGES.md'))),
  File "/tmp/pip-build-8yudAS/asyncmc/setup.py", line 8, in read
    return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), f)).read().strip()
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-build-8yudAS/asyncmc/CHANGES.md'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-8yudAS/asyncmc/
```

Comment: `pip install --upgrade setuptools`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python pip install gives "Command "python setup.py egg\_info" failed with error code 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/python-pip-install-gives-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-c)

Comment: This seems to be a bug with `asyncmc`. Try a previous version: `pip install asyncmc==0.6.5`.

Comment: @Evert: Thanks it worked!