# pip install channels:"python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python, pip, installation, django-channels

> (some_virtual_env) # pip install channels

gives me:

```
Collecting channels
  Using cached channels-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Django>=1.11 (from channels)
  Using cached Django-1.11.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting asgiref~=2.1 (from channels)
  Using cached asgiref-2.1.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting daphne~=2.0 (from channels)
  Using cached daphne-2.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /root/.virtualenvs/codebench/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Django>=1.11->channels)
Collecting async-timeout~=2.0 (from asgiref~=2.1->channels)
  Using cached async-timeout-2.0.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-iii9a6/async-timeout/setup.py", line 1, in <module>
        import pathlib
    ImportError: No module named pathlib

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-iii9a6/async-timeout/
```

I tried upgrade setuptools as described in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36025294/646732
It didn't work.

Tried:

```
(test_python3) # apt-get install python3
(test_python3) # alias python=python3
(test_python3) # pip install async-timeout
(test_python3) # python -V
Python 3.5.2
(test_python3) # pip install async-timeout
```

It gives me:

```
Collecting async-timeout
  Using cached async-timeout-2.0.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-Dw6FjJ/async-timeout/setup.py", line 1, in <module>
        import pathlib
    ImportError: No module named pathlib

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-Dw6FjJ/async-timeout/
```

Not sure what else to check and install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run below command first

```
sudo pip install pathlib
```

then

```
pip install channels
```

Comment: Any explanation for this?