# I can't install ssdeep module for python 3.4

Tags: python, python-module

I currently use python 3.4 and I also try to install ssdeep module for python. My operating system is windows 8. My best option is here: (I think) https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ssdeep, then I downloaded the tar.gz file but I get an error when I use this command in the specific directory;

```
python setup.py install
```

and the error output:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Windows 
SDK 7.1": www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=8279
```

Even though I have them installed on my computer. (I could not find any .whl file of ssdeep) I can install ssdeep on a OSX without of anything needed. So what is wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python pip install gives "Command "python setup.py egg\_info" failed with error code 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/python-pip-install-gives-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not running Windows but under Linux when you downloaded the tar.gz file you would have to extract it and then run `python setup.py install` in the extracted directory not `pip` (assuming there is a setup.py file there of course)