# error in sudo pip install azure on Raspberry bi

Tags: python, sql-server, azure

I am try to connect and use Azure MS-SQL via python on a Raspberry Pi. I did run into issues. However a blog by Marc Duiker (https://blog.marcduiker.nl/2017/07/16/installing-python-azure-sdk-raspberrypi.html) help me progress a bit down the road

One step is to install the Azure SDK via:

```
sudo pip install azure
```

But, I get the following error:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-csr10u/cryptography/

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python pip install gives "Command "python setup.py egg\_info" failed with error code 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/python-pip-install-gives-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-c)

Comment: Looks like the cryptography module is failing, do you have the same error when you do `pip install cryptography` ?

Comment: Have you tried the solutions in the thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/python-pip-install-gives-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-c?  Any further steps and progress?