# Cannot install pygtk

Tags: python, linux, gtk, installation, pygtk

I know there are a lot of posts where people had problems installing `pygtk`, but none of them actually did the trick for me.

I am running Antergos Linux.

Trying to install via `pip` gives me this:

```
$ pip install pygtk                                                                                                                                   maddin@maddins-pc
Collecting pygtk
  Using cached pygtk-2.24.0.tar.bz2
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ********************************************************************
    * Building PyGTK using distutils is only supported on windows. *
    * To build PyGTK in a supported way, read the INSTALL file.    *
    ********************************************************************

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-8n79y5by/pygtk/
```

I looked at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/pip-install-returns-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1#36025294), but none of the suggested solutions did the trick for me. So I downloaded the `tar.gz` from [here](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/pygtk/2.24/), read the `INSTALL` file and followed the instructions at the top:

./configure:

```
$ ./configure                                                                                                      maddin@maddins-pc
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for bind_textdomain_codeset... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for some Win32 platform... no
checking for native Win32... no
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ar... ar
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
configure: creating ./config.lt
config.lt: creating libtool
checking for a Python interpreter with version >= 2.3.5... python
checking for python... /usr/bin/python
checking for python version... 3.6
checking for python platform... linux
checking for python script directory... ${prefix}/lib/python3.6/site-packages
checking for python extension module directory... ${exec_prefix}/lib/python3.6/site-packages
checking for headers required to compile python extensions...   File "<string>", line 1
    import sys; print sys.prefix
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "<string>", line 1
    import sys; print sys.exec_prefix
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
found
checking for PySignal_SetWakeupFd in Python.h...   File "<string>", line 1
    import sys; print sys.prefix
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
yes
checking for python module thread... no
checking whether to enable threading in pygtk... no
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.16... yes
checking for GLIB - version >= 2.8.0... yes (version 2.56.0)
checking for PYGOBJECT... yes
checking for gio-types.defs... /usr/share/pygobject/2.0/defs/gio-types.defs
checking for ATK... yes
checking for PANGO... yes
checking for codegen... /usr/share/pygobject/2.0/codegen
checking for PYCAIRO... yes
checking for PANGOCAIRO... yes
checking for GTK... yes
checking for GTK210... yes
checking for GTK212... yes
checking for GTK214... yes
checking for GTK216... yes
checking for GTK218... yes
checking for GTK220... yes
checking for GTK222... yes
checking for GTK224... yes
checking for LIBGLADE... yes
checking for GTKUNIXPRINT... yes
checking for GDK target... x11
configure: WARNING: Could not find a valid numpy installation, disabling.
checking whether gcc understands -Wall... yes
checking whether gcc understands -fno-strict-aliasing... yes
checking whether gcc understands -std=c9x... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating pygtk-2.0.pc
config.status: creating pygtk-codegen-2.0
config.status: creating gtk/Makefile
config.status: creating docs/Makefile
config.status: creating docs/reference/entities.docbook
config.status: creating examples/Makefile
config.status: creating tests/Makefile
config.status: creating pygtk.spec
config.status: creating PKG-INFO
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands

The following modules will be built:

atk
pango
pangocairo
gtk with 2.24 API
gtk.glade
gtk.unixprint

Numpy support: no
```

make (Here comes the error):

```
$ make                                                                                                             maddin@maddins-pc
/bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/usr/include/python3.6m -I/usr/include/python3.6m -I/usr/include/pygtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/libffi-3.2.1/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I./gtk  -DDISABLE_THREADING -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -g -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -std=c9x -MT atk_la-atkmodule.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/atk_la-atkmodule.Tpo -c -o atk_la-atkmodule.lo `test -f 'atkmodule.c' || echo './'`atkmodule.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/usr/include/python3.6m -I/usr/include/python3.6m -I/usr/include/pygtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/libffi-3.2.1/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I./gtk -DDISABLE_THREADING -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -g -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -std=c9x -MT atk_la-atkmodule.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/atk_la-atkmodule.Tpo -c atkmodule.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/atk_la-atkmodule.o
atkmodule.c:36:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
 DL_EXPORT(void)
 ^~~~~~~~~
atkmodule.c: In function ‘DL_EXPORT’:
atkmodule.c:37:1: error: expected declaration specifiers before ‘initatk’
 initatk(void)
 ^~~~~~~
atkmodule.c:48:1: error: expected ‘{’ at end of input
 }
 ^
atkmodule.c:48:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
make: *** [Makefile:609: atk_la-atkmodule.lo] Error 1
```

I also tried manually specifying `./configure --prefix=/usr/bin/python3.6` as suggested in the `README` - file, but it leads to the same result.

What can I do now?

Comment: Are you aware that pygtk is outdated (gtk 2) and you should use the newer Gtk module instead, which is gtk 3? Since you're on linux, it's probably pre-installed. Try `from gi.repository import Gtk`.

Comment: yes, that does work :) Thank you! Any tips on how to find these things without making a post? And another question: I am trying to run [this sample](https://blog.mypapit.net/2009/09/pymoembed-web-browser-in-python-gtk-application.html). I have not installed `pymozembed`, but I cannot find it via `pip` neither :/ Where do I find that?

Comment: Yeah, the whole gtk2/gtk3/pygtk/gi.repository situation is pretty confusing, but all you really need to know is that pygtk is outdated and gi.repository is the way to go. I'm afraid I don't know anything about `mozembed`, but it looks like it only exists for pygtk.

Comment: Alright... I'll try finding something there then... Do you have experience in embedding webpages in gtk by any chance?

Comment: I don't, sorry.

Comment: WebKitGtk https://gist.github.com/kklimonda/890640, maybe?

Comment: It is `from gi.repository import Webkit2`. Lets not use even more unmaintained libs.