# Python Kivy: python setup.py egg_info

Tags: python, pip, kivy

Following the instructions about [Kivy](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html) but I'm getting this error when I use `python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew`

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

*Version:*

```
Python 2.7.14
pip          10.0.1
setuptools   39.0.1
wheel        0.31.0
```

Comment: Which version of Windows are your using? Please try running those commands with Administrator privilege.

Comment: Windows 10 and yes, I'm running those commands in Administrator

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/pip-install-unroll-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1) post suggests installing the setup tools, but they have more info available.