# Install Shapely in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, shapely

I cant install the shapely module in my anaconda prompt.

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools

pip install shapely 


        Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\renau\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-27xf59zz\shapely\
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install returns "python setup.py egg\_info" failed with error code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/pip-install-returns-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1)

Comment: download .whl file from [unofficial python binaries for windows](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely) and install it using `pip install <file>.whl`

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Anaconda, then it would probably be best to use:

`conda install shapely`

Answer (score 4):

i guess you are using Windows ?
if so, you can't install shapely directly via `pip`

here's the steps:

1. go to [this site](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely) and download desired version of shapely
2. run this script
   `pip install Shapely‑1.6.4.post1‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl`

here i'm going to install `Shapely` version **1.6.4** for python **3.6** running in Windows **64bit**

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get install python-shapely
```

on Python 3

```
sudo apt-get install python3-shapely
```

Comment: thanks for this answer:) could you explain why does it work?