# Installing matplotlib on Python 3.5.2 | Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: python

I tried to install matplotlib by command line:

`sudo env 'PATH=$PATH:/home/lukasz/.local/bin' pip install matplotlibpip install --upgrade setuptools`

But this error occured:

`sudo env 'python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1`

I was following steps from [pip install returns "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/pip-install-returns-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1) but i had error with command

`pip install --upgrade setuptools`: `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/__pycache__/easy_install.cpython-35.pyc`.

What can I do next?

Comment: Have you tried running that last command with sudo? It seems you have sudo access given you were using it in previous comamnds.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help achieve what you want, but try:

```
sudo pip3 install matplotlib
```

On the command line.

Comment: Do you mind if I ask why you want to install it to python 3.5 over a later version of python?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
```

and then:

```
> sudo apt install libfreetype6-dev pkg-config
```

And then:

```
> pip3 install --user matplotlib
```

or:

```
> sudo -H pip3 install matplotlib
```

I just installed it following the above steps.

Comment: 1st step works, but in 2nd/3rd  still the same error `code 1`

Answer (score 0):

Try it, It works for me:

```
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```