# Error while installing rake

Tags: python, powershell, pip

I'm trying to install rake (https://github.com/zelandiya/RAKE-tutorial) as instructed on the README file using

```
python setup.py install.
```

However, I always get the following error:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jz29g5dr\rake\
```

I tried almost everything I can find online including this comprehensive post: [pip install returns "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/pip-install-returns-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1but) still can't find the solution. Any help is needed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's the error that comes before that one? Maybe some dependency that's not available for your OS?

Comment: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting