# how to install mysqlclient in terminal (mac)

Tags: mysql, database, python-3.x, terminal, psql

I'm trying to install `mysqlclient` with the following command:

`pip install mysqlclient`

But I get the following error:

`Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/n5/_mhvyfb56zdgxxt8d7zr9_bc0000gn/T/pip-build-198s5hnh/mysqlclient/`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install returns "python setup.py egg\_info" failed with error code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/pip-install-returns-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1)

Comment: Try using sudo with you command