# Pip install Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to download a package to call **sc2** and when I write `pip install sc2` into cmd prompt, I receive the error:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-q3ixb0\websockets.

Any help?

Comment: Check this post :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/pip-install-unroll-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1

Comment: What you've posted is the generic error message which doesn't help. Post the complete output you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

**easy_install** Worked of me.

easy_install sc2

Comment: when I try to easy install i get the error "c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-a8j3lb\async-timeout-3.0.0\setup.py", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pathlib

Answer (score 0):

Maybe are you behind a proxy or not connected? has you try to make ping to any url ?